# Userscript to auto-replace SOFU links in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, userscript, internal-links

SOFU links pasted into questions get automatically replaced by the question title. This has been this way for some time now, and it's great.

However, it is missing from comments. This is very annoying, but apparently [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394/replace-links-with-the-current-question-title-in-comments), although I don't really understand why.

Anyway, seeing as this is probably unlikely to change - does a Greasemonkey or user script exist that emulates the behaviour? Meaning that if I attempt to post a comment with a raw SOFU link in it, the script automatically looks up the question title, and replaces the link, before it gets submitted.

(If it's possible at all to do this - I have no idea whether an Ajax question title lookup is doable....)

Comment: We have a whole site for standalone apps and browser enchancements to the SE network!  http://stackapps.com

Comment: @Rebecca for future reference, is Stackapps also the  right place to *request* stuff that doesn't yet exist there?

Comment: http://stackapps.com/questions/2378/se-comment-link-helper

Comment: Unfortunately Userscripts aren't available on mobiles/ipad

Comment: I posted a related userscript at [Add markdown quick-links to the share dialog?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232107/185667)

Comment: I also posted a related userscript at [Add markdown quick-links to the share dialog?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296653/230261).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wrote a script for this purpose. Please see [this StackApps posting](https://stackapps.com/q/2378/4746) for more information.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much! I will look into this later today.

Comment: Very nice, works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: one more report, I cannot paste deleted post link anymore - probably getting error and comment does not get submitted.

Comment: @YOU Ah, good catch, this should be fixed now (it'll just leave the link as-is)

Comment: Nice, its working now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

As a workaround, George Edison was kind enough to write [Copy Question Link Markdown - Making it easier to copy links to questions!](https://stackapps.com/questions/2150/copy-question-link-markdown-making-it-easier-to-copy-links-to-questions) This script adds a `copy` button to questions, which generates markdown with the link and question title, e.g. `[Userscript to auto-replace SOFU links in comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89378/userscript-to-auto-replace-sofu-links-in-comments)`.

Note that both the link text and the description text will count against the comment length limit. You may want to trim the URL down to `http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89378`.

Comment: Excellent, this is a big step already!

Comment: @Pekka: That's a great idea for my script (trimming the length of the generated URL).