# Include comment markdown formatting in "Share" link

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, markdown, share-this

I find I often want to link to other related questions in comments and frequently use the "Share" link below a question:

[image]

Invariably, I also want to share the title for a readable link, so the procedure goes something like this:

- Copy the link as above
- Type `[]()` into the comment field
- Paste the link `[](https://somestack.com/q/12345/678901)`
- Return to the question and copy the title
- Return to the comment and paste the title

> [
> Meta Stack Exchange
> How can I fix this McGuffin?] (https://somestack.com/q/12345/678901)

- Remove extraneous hidden cruft inserted onto the clipboard title copy
- `[How can I fix this McGuffin?](https://somestack.com/q/12345/678901)`
- Post

On desktop this is tedious; on mobile it's much worse.

It would be terribly convenient if the share link also included the option to copy a comment-markdown formatted link in this format.  This has come up in the past and users variously have scripting workarounds and other hacks to make this easier, but it would be altogether simpler if this functionality was built right into the site.

Linking duplicates and related content is something Stack Exchange seems to continue to struggle with, with new answers and questions being heavily favoured over redirecting to existing questions and answers.  Improving the functionality here would perhaps help to encourage more interaction on this front.

This has been discussed previously, but it has been at least six years since the last time something related was requested so let's revisit.  The implementation is trivially simple.

- [Replace links with the current question title in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77394/222049)
- [Add a second 'share' button to posts with comment-ready links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126544/222049)
- [Copy link to a post as markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254466/222049)

Comment: I also use a user script of my own that does exactly that.

Comment: The links to user scripts and various other workarounds are already in the linked questions (and answers).  This isn't a request for temporary solutions - we understand how to hack this behaviour out of a script.  I'd like the stack experience to start requiring **fewer** user scripts rather than more.  For people who always use the same computer all day, every day, a script is a serviceable workaround.  It gets tiring when you need to install a suite of hacks on every new system you end up working at, however.

Comment: I usually copy the link in full from the address bar or from the question title (which is a link to itself). This link includes the text of the title, instead of just the numeric question id from the Share link. Then I paste the raw link in a comment. For short titles (20 characters or so) the full url, including the title, is shown in the comment. For longer titles the link is truncated, but the tooltip still shows the title. However I do support your request, this would be more clear than raw links with tooltips (you could even say it is more _welcoming_...)

Comment: @Marijn True, but the same time using the address bar link nullifies unicorn points for Announcer/Booster/Publicist badges.  This frustrates the end goal of wanting to encourage people to improve the quality of internal links between related questions and answers by removing what little reward exists for doing so.

Comment: I feel like I spend a lot of time formatting links like this. In the new editor available here on meta and Teams, you can copy and paste the question title into WSIWG mode and it'll keep the link format (and the h1 format, unfortunately).

Answer (score 3):

While I understand the use cases you mention and how this can be annoying on mobile devices, I don't see this feature getting prioritized any time soon — as such, I'm [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)'ing it.

While there are indeed some limitations to the functionality — it doesn't work on comments — [SevenSidedDie's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254469/208518) to one of the posts you link to shows how there is some built-in functionality to make this easier on posts.