# Adding a 'Markdown link' to 'Share a link to this answer/question' dialog

Tags: feature-request, markdown, hyperlinks

I often prepare an answer in a local application editor that supports Markdown syntax.

After posting the answer I then add a link to that answer using the 'Copy link' of the 'Share a link to this answer' dialog.

[image]

- https://history.stackexchange.com/a/68934/38607

I then create a Markdown link that contains the original question:

- `[Answer to: Was the unemployment rate in the Nazi regime lower than the Weimar Republic? - History Stack Exchange](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/68934/38607)`

  - [Answer to: Was the unemployment rate in the Nazi regime lower than the Weimar Republic? - History Stack Exchange](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/68934/38607)

Adding a 'Copy markdown link' to this dialog would be a useful feature, not only for my usage, but also when posting comments that refer to an existing answer.

The corresponding Markdown link from 'Share a link to this question' could then contain '**Question:**' instead of '**Answer to:**'.

Many comments contain only the raw link since the building of the Markdown content is time-consuming, forcing others to go to the link just to see what it contains.

This could be avoided with a more readable text as link, that would be in a more recognisable manner (including the distinction between a referenced question or answer).

Comment: Related: [Add a second 'share' button to posts with comment-ready links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126544/add-a-second-share-button-to-posts-with-comment-ready-links), [Copy link to a post as markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254466/copy-link-to-a-post-as-markdown), [Include comment markdown formatting in "Share" link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366938/include-comment-markdown-formatting-in-share-link), [Replace links with the current question title in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77394/222049)

Comment: I don't know if it helps much, but I have made [my own userscript that adds this functionality](https://github.com/PurpleMagick/so_userscript-share-questions-as-markdown). It formats a link like so: `[Adding a 'Markdown link' to 'Share a link to this answer' dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378574)` stripping away the user ID from the link, as I'm not a fan of sharing it.

Comment: @VLAZ I work primarly with android browser, so a Javascript really doesn't resolve the problem for me. Also many comments contain only the raw link since the building of the markdown is time consuming, forcing others to goto the link just to see what it contains. This could be avoided with a more readable text as link.