# Add markdown quick-links to the share dialog?

Tags: feature-request, share-this

When I wish to share a link to a post in a comment this is my workflow:

- write `[]()`
- search for the question
- remember the title of the question
- click on the share box
- copy the link
- paste into parentheses
- write the title in the square brackets

  - realize the title is probably wrong
  - back to the question copy the title
  - paste into square brackets
- write the rest of the comment etc.

Maybe there's something obvious I've missed for 3 years, but *especially* on a mobile device or the mobile app this is very tedious.

Through debate on a [question on meta.stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) (and having seen [the referenced meta.programmers FAQ](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted)) a "new" standard is appearing of adding a markdown copy-past snippet to FAQ questions

[image: quick links in FAQ post bodies]

This makes it easy to quickly refer users to a question/answer in comments (and chat).

Should a markdown link be part of the platform, e.g. added to the share box directly?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394/replace-links-with-the-current-question-title-in-comments

Comment: @AD7six or you could do what I do and make your workflow a lot simpler.  (1) type the `[]()` (2) open search in a new tab. (3) find question (4) copy link and paste back in first tab (5) go back to 2nd tab and copy title and paste. .... now a way to do this in 1 or 2 clicks would be easier, but a lot simpler than what you do

Comment: @psubsee2003 That's no different than I put in the question, just always-assuming I can't remember the title (would be slightly streamlined though!). However, of most relevance that's an absolute PITA on a mobile device - at least on android you're pretty much guaranteed to overwrite at least one of the parentheses on paste, but that's of course not SE's fault.

Answer (score 7):

This always bugged me too. And I created a couple of solutions:

## Userscript

[**Convert share links to markdown [title](url)**](https://stackapps.com/q/4905/10590), available at Stack Apps.

The script opens with Markup as default:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

And clicking `clean url` will restore the original link:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

## JavaScript/jQuery bookmarklet

<sup>See [*Create Bookmarklets - The Right Way*](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-bookmarklets-the-right-way--net-18154)</sup>

- Open the browser bookmark manager.
- Add a new one with a short title and position it on the bookmark bar.
- Paste the following as the URL:

  ```javascript
  javascript:(function(){ $tit = $('#question-header h1 a').text(); $('#question .post-menu .short-link').click(); $url = $('.share-tip input').val(); $('.share-tip a.close-share-tip').click(); $result = '[' + $tit + '](' + $url + ')'; window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", $result); })();
  ```
- Clicking the bookmarklet will open a browser dialog with the `[title](link)` text ready to copy:

  <kbd>[image]</kbd>

Here's the unminified script:

```javascript
javascript:(function(){ 
    $tit = $('#question-header h1 a').text(); 
    $('#question .post-menu .short-link').click(); 
    $url = $('.share-tip input').val(); 
    $('.share-tip a.close-share-tip').click(); 
    $result = '[' + $tit + '](' + $url + ')'; 
    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/6055620/1287812
    window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", $result); 
})();
```

---

<sup>***bonus***</sup>
Here's another version with pure JavaScript that works with any site:

```javascript
javascript:(function(){ var result='['+document.title+']('+document.URL+')'; window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", result); })();
```

Answer (score 1):

I also would like to see this be an actual feature. I've made [another userscript to do this](https://stackapps.com/questions/7403/more-share-links-markdown-html-bbcode), similar to [brasofilo's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239362/230261) but this adds multiple options as well as keeping the original URL-only link:

[image]