# (more) Advanced Search Options

Tags: feature-request, search

How do I perform boolean (AND and OR) searches and negation?  Note:  I couldn't find this information in other "advanced search" questions ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1114/additional-search-features-syntax)) ([2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1010/advanced-syntax-ideas)) or in [Search Tips](https://stackoverflow.com/search).

I am searching Stack Overflow for ["Google Checkout"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22google+checkout) questions.  My search gives me a few results tagged [google-checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-checkout), but I also get lots of questions about various revision control systems **checkout** command.  I've tried to remove "SVN" from my search via the following methods, but none of them seem to work:

- ["google checkout" !svn](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22google+checkout%22+!svn)
- ["google checkout" not svn](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22google+checkout%22+not+svn)
- ["google checkout" ~svn](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22google+checkout%22+~svn)

Why don't I just look at the questions in the [google-checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-checkout) tag?  Because many questions were incorrectly tagged as both [google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google) and [checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checkout) (I'm fixing the problems as I see them).

Please re-tag appropriately (i.e. is this a support question or feature request?)

---

Jeff mentioned how to exclude a tag from a search:

> "google checkout" -[svn]

will search for the phrase "google checkout" while excluding all items tagged [svn].  It looks like the syntax for excluding tags **-[tag]** is missing from the [Search Tips](https://stackoverflow.com/search) page.  Could someone add it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

hmm, well, have you tried

"google checkout" -[svn]

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/

Hmm, now that I look at that, I guess this *wasn't* really documented anywhere. My bad. :(

Comment: @jeff is this a documented feature?

Comment: This still needs to be documented (4 years later)

Comment: ...and still requires documentation now.