# How to search questions with nottagged?

Tags: support, search

On [Search box](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search),

I could search following (questions tagged bug, and google-chrome, and "browser" in post)

```
[bug] [google-chrome] "browser"
```

but following does not work (intended to search same as above but not tagged with google-chrome)

```
[bug] -[google-chrome] "browser"
```

Jeff mentioned something about `-` on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11338/more-advanced-search-options/11350#11350) post, but that does not work.

Or Am I missing something?

Comment: Probably related to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49898/complex-tag-searches-yield-unexplained-results-inconsistent-with-actual-logic). Jeff really needs to fix this stuff up properly, it's getting quite annoying. :(

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you could (at least temporarily) add `[google-chrome]` to your list of ignored tags and then just search on

```
[bug] "browser"
```

Not perfect since the questions with `[google-chrome]` will still show up, but at least they won't stand out and it's easier to filter over them visually.

Comment: If I set "Hide Ignored Tags", it won't show up, but its far from workaround, because several actions involved. But +1 because it still work. But I wish built-in support from search box.