# Allow suppression of automatic linking of web addresses

Tags: feature-request, markdown, hyperlinks

As most of you know, putting a link into a post automatically makes it a link (e.g. http://localhost/) We can force the linkification with angle brackets (`<http://localhost/>`) if the markdown somehow misses it. But (as far as I know) there's no way to force the address to not be made a link.  Such a feature would be nice when we need example addresses, there's no reason to have a link to http://www.example.com/, for instance, or http://1.2.3.4/domain.com/, from the question where I thought of this.

I think an easy way to mark this up would be something like `<!http://example.com>`, making the address appear in plain text without the hyperlink.

This came to my attention in this question: [can't open transfered website from old DS to new DS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19250/cant-open-transfered-website-from-old-ds-to-new-ds)

Comment: As for any nice feature that is not essential for SE sites to operate correctly, I'd say: first convince [the author of the Markdown specification](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)...

Comment: @arjan technically auto-linking isn't part of the markdown spec. Technically, per the spec, only links in angle brackets are supposed to auto-link, but this is.. not how the world expects things to work these days.

Comment: True, @Jeff (though I did not even realize that). Still then, defining `!<...>` would be a deviation from the original Markdown that other parsers won't understand? Bare URLs might simply not be auto-linked by other parsers, but such does not really break the rendering, nor the content. (Related: I like the syntax for spoiler text, which does not break other parsers either.)

Comment: I thought I was going crazy, because all of the examples here whereby it's not supposed to create a link are appearing as links. Then I remembered I have a Chrome extension that turns non-linked URLs into links.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> `http<nolink>://www.google.com/`

> http://www.google.com/

Implementation changes might break this, but for now you can use any non-whitelisted HTML-like-code to prevent the auto-linker from kicking in, despite the code being stripped.

This doesn't work in chat or comments.

Comment: An alternative is to use `[http://www.google.com/]()`. The empty URL part causes the link to not be functional.

Answer (score 20):

If you put the link in code tags, it won't be linked automatically.

Like this:

`http://stackoverflow.com`

What I did was use the backtick `` `marks around it, so it works inline, too.`http://www.google.com` like that.

This would make semantic sense, too; because if you are wanting to insert a URL but don't want it to operate as a link, it's almost always because it's in code, or a value for some code.

Comment: I know it doesn't link in code, but I feel that unnecessarily highlights the address. I just want it to look like normal text.

Comment: I think the use for that would be minimal (though obviously, you disagree). I suppose you could always do something like insert the HTML code for a zero-width space or some such.

Comment: Can't you just drop the `http://` then, @Kevin?

Comment: @arjan that was also the answer when this came up recently in the context of "why can't the tooltip text for a URL itself be a hyperlink too", which I consider a rather.. insanely obscure.. request.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `&period;` markup code for the dot in, e.g., dot com:

```
This should not be automatically parsed: just-text&period;com
```

Comment: `https://` seems to be required. At least here.

Comment: Well the preview parse the link even with &period; however when actually posted it's not parsed.