# How do I write a URL with internal formatting without having it auto-link?

Tags: discussion, markdown, hyperlinks

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24616/how-do-i-write-a-url-in-a-comment-without-making-it-a-link) answers how to write a URL in a comment without making it auto-link (using the '`' character).

How do I write a URL with **internal** formatting (**bold** or *italics* or ***both***) without having it auto-link?

Example: http:// www.**boldtext**.com/not_bold_at_all.html

(Note: I had to put a space after the second `/` to get this to submit properly).

For example, I just edited [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295399/how-do-i-configure-iis-web-config-to-redirect-domains-but-maintain-the-target-f) where two unlinked URLs are presented for comparison, and a section changes in each url; in my opinion, that change should be emphasized for readability.

After writing this question, I suspect the solutions could be

1. don't preface the url with http://, and instead just write the domain path out and highlight the appropriate sections.
2. put a space after the second /, as I did in my example above, which isn't an apparent solution to most users
3. preface the "http{s}://" section with a "don't auto-link" special-character

Are any of the above preferable solutions to this dilemma, or is there an implemented alternative?

Test: `<code>http://www.mysite.com/<b>subfolder</b></code>` as `http://www.mysite.com/subfolder` doesn't work.

Comment: Related: *[Allow suppression of automatic linking of web addresses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119801/allow-suppression-of-automatic-linking-of-web-addresses/119811#119811)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nest the formatting. **`http://stackoverflow.com`** is a bold non-clickable link, formatted as:

```
**`http://stackoverflow.com`**
```

To make it italics as well, simply add underscores or more asterixes: ***`http://stackoverflow.com`***

You cannot use MarkDown for inter-word formatting though. You'll have to switch to using HTML markup:

`http://stackoverflow.com`

is formatted with

```
<code>http://<b>stack</b><i>overflow</i>.com</code>
```

To completely defeat the auto-linker however, you need to replace *any one* character in start of the URL with an entity character:

- http://stackoverflow/**questions**/ (uses `&colon;` instead of `:`)
- http://stackoverflow/**questions**/ (uses `&#47;` instead of `/`)

Comment: Revised the question; I'm looking for how to format specific internal portions of the URL, not the entire URL.

Comment: @JoshDM: I saw the switch, edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: OY.  ***SLAPS FOREHEAD***.  I have been habitually conditioned to NOT use HTML within comments, so that super-obvious solution simply didn't occur to me. A+.

Comment: `<code>http://www.mysite.com/<b>subfolder</b></code>`  doesn't work.  Your use of the bold entity immediately after the last `/` is why yours works.

Comment: While more complete, Goran beat you to it by 6 minutes, Martijn. :-D

Comment: @JoshDM: that's life while multitasking! :-)

Comment: @JoshDM, If Martijn's answer is better, then it is common practice to unaccept the lower quality answer and accept the higher quality, as long as it answers the question better and/or in more detail.

Comment: @Grammar - done for legacy reasons, but a question to that point (as I know Martijn didn't actually do what I'm about to posit); what if someone went through and edited their question deliberately to snipe "better" suggestions from other answers in the same question in order to just create a more comprehensive answer with the intent to build reputation?

Comment: Josh, most of SO (me included) will incorporate other's answers into our own, to make them more complete and help more. We do this so that all the information is in a single post, because many visitors only read the accepted answer to fix a problem. Naturally, this habit will carry over onto meta. Auto-correct, stop changing META to MEAT, please.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a character entity for one of the characters that trigger the auto-linking.

So

`http&colon;//www.**boldtext**.com/not_bold_at_all.html`

will display as

http://www.**boldtext**.com/not_bold_at_all.html

Comment: This is a much better solution, as it solves the problem where the formatted section isn't the first section.