# Bounty Hunter badges

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges, bounties, badge-request

I suggest two new badges:

1. **Greedo** - first bounty earned (bronze)
2. **Boba Fett** - earned 2000 rep through bounty (silver)

---

Imported from UserVoice ticket, "[Bounty hunter badges](https://web.archive.org/web/20090705091639/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/110435-bounty-hunter-badges)", originally posted by Jon Skeet.

Comment: It's not so easy to win a bounty, I'd make them silver/gold

Comment: No way!  I want an IG-88 (http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/IG-88) badge!

Comment: IG-88 should be somewhere in between Greedo and Boba Fett.  (All the information we have indicates that Greedo kind of sucked.)

Comment: @Bill: yeah, Greedo should be awarded for losing a bounty at the last second.

Comment: “Bounty Hunters. We don’t need that scum!”

Comment: I'd rather have a Samus Aran badge

Comment: @Sam - Nerd fail. The quote (according to IMDB and Wookiepedia) is "Bounty hunters. We don't need their scum."

Comment: We now need a `Greedo-Shot-First` badge and a `Han-Shot-First` badge to quell the dust you've stirred up by mentioning Greedo.

Comment: I am confused:  how is this [tag:status-completed]?  I don't see any badges for winning bounty listed.

Comment: @Jeff why did you mark it status-completed?

Comment: @sha see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/a-bevy-of-new-badges/

Comment: @Jeff I saw it - the word "bounty" is not even mentioned there.. sorry, I'm confused.

Comment: @sha ack you're right. But see the badge list at http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59064

Comment: @Jeff OK fair enough - but looks like this feature request should be marked as declined. Better late than never, if you ask me. :)

Comment: @JeffAtwood so badges are to teach new users and encourage positive activities... which one of those does Tumbleweed fall into?

Comment: On the off chance this does get implemented, might I nominate Spike Spiegel for a badge name?

Comment: This is the worst `status-completed` of all time.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ Correction: this is now the worst `status-declined` of all time.

Comment: Would love to see this implemented - I feel that simply being awarded the bounty wouldn't be sufficient enough to merit the badge.  I'll flesh out some ideas a bit after the holiday.

Comment: Since neither [Jeff Atwood](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/bounty-hunter-badges/59064#59064) nor [Sam Saffron](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/bounty-hunter-badges/56243#56243) work at Stack Exchange anymore ([they've moved on to Discourse](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2013/02/civilized-discourse-construction-kit.html)), can the Stack Exchange staff listen to the community now and implement Bounty Hunter badges?

Comment: Or will this forever be a case of [Listen to Your Community, But Don't Let Them Tell You What to Do](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/02/listen-to-your-community-but-dont-let-them-tell-you-what-to-do.html)?

Comment: How come that a suggestion with 100+ upvotes gets `declined`? I am confused..

Comment: I had the same idea as a new user SO -- found this question through google.  It's obvious why this feature should exist as the votes reflect.  It's a shame this isn't being implemented.

Answer (score 44):

Actually that's not bad, both in concept and execution.  I'd second that.

Answer (score 44):

I definitely want the badges implemented. I would prefer the following however:

- Bronze for first bounty win
- Silver for bounty win worth X amount of rep (say minimum of 200)
- Gold for bounty win worth Y amount of rep (say minimum of 500)
- Gold for total bounties won worth over 2000 rep

Answer (score 27):

I was about to submit a duplicate question before I searched and found this one.

- 1 bounty won - "Bounty Hunter"
- 10 bounties won...
- 100 bounties won...

Maybe we could also (as in have both) award badges for rep won from bounties

- 100 Jango Fett badge
- 1000 Greedo badge
- 5000 Boba Fett badge

Here are some supporting links for more bounty features:

1. [Winning your own bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3167/badge-for-winning-your-own-bounty)
2. [More tag badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8126/more-tag-badges)
3. [Limits on bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3434/we-penalise-people-for-asking-questions-nobody-else-is-interested-in-is-this-int) - also see Jeff's comment on Tim's answer near the bottom
4. [Request for bounty stat display features](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3563/please-list-bounties-a-user-both-participated-in-and-won)

Comment: Do you get a "Jenga" Fett badge if someone knocks over your stack of wooden blocks. http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jango_Fett

Comment: I like the concept, but 100 bounties is just too much to be reasonable. 25 should deserve gold.

Answer (score 27):

I think despite the common objection, this badge would be a *good* idea for a few reasons:

1. **Badges are different from rep**
   @Tomas' analogy is apt. "Reputation is like money, whereas a badge is like a present!" When they award a Nobel prize, they don't say "8 million dollars should be enough award for anyone", they also give you a diploma and a gold medal. You could buy a lot of diplomas and gold medals with 8 million dollars, but *that isn't really the point*.
2. **Plenty of bounties go un-awarded**
   Whether you look at the numbers by total rep or by [count](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/86142/unawarded-bounties-count) on new Questions from January-September about 1/3 have gone un-awarded. That isn't a terrible number, and I realize from looking at that queue myself that's partially because some of the questions that get bountied are just terrible questions to begin with.
3. **It isn't really terribly easy to get a lot of rep from answering bounties**
   Notable exceptions aside (*cough* @MrGomez), your average rep whore's time is better spent trying to provide definitive answers to fairly simple questions.
4. **Bounties are only offered by contributing members of the community**
   If what it takes for some expert in some obscure technology to click on the 'Featured' tab every so often to check for some troubled community member completely stuck on the same is the promise of accumulating points toward some random badge, I don't see a downside to that.

**TLDR version:** To me, the reward of helping out on bounty questions is simply helping another developer with a last-ditch attempt to get a problem solved. I really don't see how adding a silly badge or two if it encourages some people to try to do that more often can really be a *bad* thing.

Comment: *3* is probably not true. Bountied questions are seen more (by virtue of the bounty). So a good answer will likely get significantly more upvotes than a similarly good answer on a non-bountied question. Posting good answers on bountied questions is a good rep-building strategy even if the possibility of earning a bounty is disregarded.

Comment: @EliahKagan I tend to think of bounties as being mainly useful for solving relatively obscure problems. True there is a huge exposure benefit to posting a good answer on a bountied question, but that benefit quickly evaporates when potential voters can't easily verify your information.

Answer (score 7):

I've been thinking something like kelly s french's idea.

After seeing this thread, I'm surprised something like it hasn't been implemented.

I feel 100 bounties is too high a bar to shoot for gold.

- 1 bounty awarded (**Hired Gun**)
- 10 bounties awarded (**Bounty Hunter**)
- 25 bounties awarded (**Soldier of Fortune**)

Instead (or in addition)

- 100 rep awarded  (**Jango Fett**)
- 1000 rep awarded  (**Colt Sever**)
- 2500 rep awarded  (**Boba Fett**)

Answer (score 6):

It would be good to have badges based on answering bounty questions, to stimulate more people working on answering them.  Competition is a healthy thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is really old, nonetheless I think it should be declined.

People who win bounties already get a big reputation bump, additionally we are adding 4 bounty related bronze badges for the people we create bounties. Mainly to teach people how the system works.

People who win bounties already get a substantial reward, a huge reputation bump. Additionally, with the badge changes it will be possible to browse through all the bounty questions.

Comment: This is true, however the badge is not only about a reward... it's also about characterizing you. Reputation is not what we want... **reputation is like money**, whereas **badge is like a present!** Money anonymously merges with another money, gets spent... but presents (and badges) remain forever as a nice esteem... BTW, would you be satisfied to get money instead of a present for Christmas? Me not!

Comment: @Tomas money could be at some point a present, therefore the word "instead" in your example is not 100% correct

Comment: The "huge" boost can be as little as 50, which compares to a modestly popular answer. A "bounty hunter" would be someone who actively helps people with special needs, which is quite a different domain, I think...

Answer (score -28):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/improvements-to-badge-system/

implemented as

- promoter
- benefactor
- investor
- altruist

Comment: This seems like a stretch... the OP wanted badges for _earning_ bounties, but the listed badges are related to _offering_ bounties.

Comment: @pop see waffles' answer

Comment: @JeffAtwood, waffles' answer is no convincing, we have extra badges Legendary, Epic and Mortarboard for rewarding big reputation bump. Why can't bounty earning apply the same scenario. Besides, voting in this thread really tells all. Most people want Bounty Hunter badges.

Comment: @JeffAtwood what happened to waffles' answer? I don't see it here anymore.

Comment: Never mind, I was [told by animuson](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137221/where-are-bounty-hunter-badges?noredirect=1#comment591647_137221) that [waffles is Sam Saffron](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/sam-saffron), so his answer would be, in fact, [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/bounty-hunter-badges/56243#56243).

Comment: now who gave this man a bounty?