# Badge for winning your own bounty

Tags: feature-request, badges, bounties

This would probably be a difficult feat, but could we have a badge for winning your own bounty? Maybe something along the lines of "Self-Poacher".

Would anyone even qualify for the badge right now?

Comment: Two possible reasons:
1. You found the answer yourself some time after offering the bounty. 2. You want that self-poacher badge.

Comment: It could be this one or another related to bounties, but we definitely need a "Boba Fett" badge.

Comment: What can stop someone from putting out a fat bounty, getting the right answer from someone, then saying that they found the answer themselves?  I say once the bounty is offered they shouldn't get it back..at least if someone else voted up an answer.

Comment: @Lars 3. Someone running sock puppets who outvoted everyone else.  It has and does happen ....

Answer (score 4):

Since you can't accept your own answer to a bounty question, I assume you mean "your own answer is the highest-voted answer at the end of the week."

Would you get half your bounty points back, in that case?

Badge is an interesting idea, though.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Has there been an instance of this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be a be to recall a bounty you put out, if you figured out your problem, but I don't think doing that should be rewarded with a badge.

To kind of steal from one of Joel's comments in an early podcast, I don't think Napoleon would have given you a little piece of colored cloth for doing this.

Comment: recalling a bounty can be seen as bait and switch for those 'bounty hunters' out there.  I say take the loss... but what if your own boring question has an answer you like but never gets an upvote?

Answer (score 0):

If there were methods to define your own [private badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4870/what-would-you-contribute-or-try-to-to-an-open-sourced-stackoverflow/4881#4881), you could do that and still be hidden from the others - if that makes you happy. In general, the ability to have your own near-real-time metrics about your performance might be an interesting thing too.