# Anyone have code for posting questions to stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, robots

I know a few bots have been identified previously, and it wouldn't surprise me if some had experimented with posting questions using code.

I'd rather not re-invent the wheel, and this seems the best place to ask.

What code do you have or know of that is capable of posting new questions to stackoverflow?

Small print:

<sup>I'm working on http://stackoverflowoverflow.stackexchange.com - the idea is to take closed questions from SO and post them there for those that want to continue off-topic conversations in a stackoverflow-like environment.  The code for posting to a stackexchange site should be essentially the same as code for stackoverflow. I've asked for code examples at [stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4891/automate-question-insertion-workaround), but I imagine there are more SO bot developers here than there.  I also know that if I post it on SO it'll get sent here post-haste, so here we are.</sup>

Comment: And it's really tedious transferring the questions over by hand...

Comment: belongs on meta.stackoverflowoverflow.com

Comment: This is from before SE2.0 days, right?

Comment: @AnnaLear, yes. Stackoverflowoverflow was [actually briefly live](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46551/stackoverflowoverflow-to-be-or-not-to-be), but it never really got off the ground. (See also Pollyadam's answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41772/131713).) (Edit again: archive.org does have a few old snaps of it [sans styles](http://web.archive.org/web/20100427164237/http://stackoverflowoverflow.stackexchange.com/).)

Answer (score 4):

If you have a valid user's auth cookie, it should be possible, if you pay attention to what the JavaScript is doing on the page.

The SE codebase is far enough out of sync with ours now that I can't actually tell you what will work and what won't any more.