# Should we have another site for non-technical aspects of IT?

Tags: discussion

For example

- Project Manager discussion (how to deal with customers, how to ask for more budget etc)
- Which ERP solution to choose for this kind of business at this scale
- How to manage your IT career
- If you jump from IT to other career, what would be your strength (and how to maximize it) and what would be your weakness

Thanks

Comment: What's you goal with this question? Does this relate anyhow to stackoverflow or sister site self?

Comment: Just updated the title to explain it clearly. I wonder if we can have some SO-related site to discuss those matters

Comment: See this question - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42373/what-sites-are-currently-missing-from-the-trilogy and the related blog post - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46551/stackoverflowoverflow-to-be-or-not-to-be ?

Answer (score 1):

Not a terrible idea, but I don't think there would be nearly enough questions or traffic to warrant it.

Answer (score 0):

http://careeroverflow.com does already exist.

Not part of the trilogy, but it's using the same Stackexchange website engine and that seems to be your major concern. For other Stackexchange based sites, look here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites