# Is the "Not Programming Related" site proposal appropriate?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange-2.0, site-proposal

I've been looking forward to [Not Programming Related](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352/not-programming-related) since before Area 51 existed (anyone remember [StackOverflowOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46551/stackoverflowoverflow-to-be-or-not-to-be)?).  NPR even has [Jeff's support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling/57384#57384).  But lately I've been wondering whether it's an appropriate site for the SE family.

As far as I can tell, all of the SE sites are holding at least moderately firmly to the "don't make subjective discussion posts, this is a place for questions that can be answered" mantra.  And let's face it, that's kind of what makes an SE site an SE site.  But NPR is, by its very nature, for more subjective, discussion-y questions.  Is making NPR a reality worth breaking with the SE brand?  I'm worried that it'll embolden people who want to have discussions on other SE sites.  Will it lead to other SE sites asking for subjective spinoffs?  Would that be bad?

Comment: Proposals for *Not User Related* and *Not Server Related* in 3... 2... 1...

Comment: @Andy Psh, *Not Super Related* would be so much better.

Comment: I really hope it's implemented, and then I hope they create a 'vote to close as 'Belongs on Not Programming Related'. I'd spend all my close votes just for that.

Comment: just combine them all into "Unrelated"; that would give us only one site to never visit instead of 4 ;-)

Comment: What George said. SO *needs* a dumping ground, but we're not supposed to be using SU for that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what betas are for.

I think the name is not appropriate, but it would be worth (and perhaps interesting) to try the engine on this kind of subjective, discussion-y questions as you call them.

If it doesn't work, the site just won't graduate from beta and that would be it.

Comment: I'm sure it would work.  But I wonder if it would confuse people about what Stack Exchange _is_.  I wonder if it would _change_ what Stack Exchange is.

Comment: @Pop, well... it works now... meta is mostly discussion; then you're right, the debate is if the concept of SE will change.

Comment: @Pop: I think "what Stack Exchange is" is still being defined, especially now that *non-technical* sites are progressing farther along.  The team probably doesn't agree with this *yet*, but I think the future of SE may hold several meta sub-sites or "sister sites" that are "designated [discussion] areas", with [discussion] optionally replaceable by whatever else you don't want cluttering up the parent site but the community's fifth column just won't leave alone.

Comment: Looks like people are on board with this experiment.  Time to bring down Stack Exchange as we know it, I guess.  (Except that I'm out of commitment tokens.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm personally all for these proposals and any other similar "spin-offs" that mean we can migrate all questions like *Favorite Programmer Cartoon* to those sites.  Mostly because I'm sick of voting to close questions only to be asked *"If Favorite Programmer Cartoon gets to stay why can't my question?"*.

Comment: that's what I thought at first, but I think the question will just turn into "well that site has polls and discussions, why can't this one?"

Comment: @Popular We could probably address that in the same fashion that we could address "Well, Stack Overflow has questions about programming, so why can't I ask it here on Gaming?". That's what scope is all about.

Comment: @Pop: Maybe, but if the question can be migrated there then maybe the user won't have any complaints?

Comment: Since the whole issue will arise for all betas, too, I proposed the [Fourth place, polling et al](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling) to move FPC&al to, without having to propose a not[whatever]related site for everything... (also @Popular Demand I guess)