# Are area51 proposals that intentionally deal with subjective questions allowed?

Tags: discussion, area-51, subjective, site-proposal

[Not Programming Related](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352/not-programming-related) (besides having a misleading name that will only confuse people that aren't familiar with stack overflow) is for:

> expert programmers interested in
>   discussions that are only indirectly
>   related to programming

All the most voted on-topic questions are subjective:

- My supervisor thinks that all `If` statements should include `else` statements. Do you agree?
- Tabs vs. Spaces: What is the one proper indentation character for everything, in every situation, ever?
- What are common mistakes in Software Development?
- What is your favorite programming joke?
- What’s your favorite “programmer” cartoon?

All the most voted off-topic questions are not subjective.

This is exactly contrary to what the area51 FAQ suggests:

> Ask questions that can be answered.
>   Avoid asking question that are
>   subjective, argumentative, or require
>   extended discussion. Stack Exchange
>   does not work well with questions like
>   "Which is the best..."

Since Jeff Atwood himself committed, I assume it's allowed, at least in this case (and I'm happy; sounds like an interesting website). But is this an "exception" to the rule, or are websites dedicated to subjective questions indeed allowed?

Comment: Also brought up here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58216/is-the-not-programming-related-site-proposal-appropriate

Answer (score 1):

There is often no hard line between subjective and objective. Each SE site must define this boundary for itself. I think oh-my-god-all-the-way-full-on subjective questions just plain don't work with the SO/SE paradigm. Hence, any proposals that are *too* subjective should be discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

The Not Programming Related site is intended to be a home for all of those contentious questions on SO that get closed and reopened repeatedly due to their off-topic flavor.  Hence, I see it as an exception to the rule, an oasis where the inclusionists can protect their popular, but off-topic questions without fear of reprisals.

It wouldn't surprise me if a feature is added to StackOverflow that will allow "off-topic" posts on StackOverflow to migrate here when they are closed.

Comment: I think that this would be an interesting test to see how well these kinds of questions go. This might help us refine the limits on what is and what is not allowed on StackOverflow