# Can "user profile views" NOT include narcissism please?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, views, profile-page

Based on [Does "user profile views" include narcissism?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12744/does-user-profile-views-include-narcissism), it looks like visiting our own profile increases the number of 'views' listed there.

Can it NOT please? I'm not interested in how many times I've been there.

Rob

Comment: I've decided to list this as both a bug and a feature-request. I get why it's probably a feature-request, but I also think it's a bug that the views reports our own profile views. So it fits in both camps...

Comment: stop looking in the mirror so much! gosh!

Comment: Yeah - I know... it's just that you put so much useful information on that page, like links to recent posts. It's not me, it's you. Err...

Comment: But seriously Jeff... presumably you store something about who has visited the profile - so you could potentially show things like "How many different users have viewed your profile", and exclude anonymous and self-visits?

Comment: But it's not narcissistic to want to know how many *other* people look at you? O_O

Comment: Haha, true Jeff. It's all about the narcissism. If it was just altruism, then there wouldn't be badges or reputation points.

Comment: i didn't even know there was a count of profile views. so is this fix retroactive, or does the count include my own views from before the rule changed?

Comment: JA - if this is done, can you post a quick answer saying what's changed? Then I'll accept that answer. :) Thanks...

Comment: Kip - must be the latter. I'm sure my count would've dropped significantly if it was retrospective.

Comment: Is there a way to see who viewed/visited ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Jeff says this is completed, so I'm going to mark it as answered. I wanted Jeff to post something, but instead I'll accept this one.

Answer (score 18):

I whole-heartedly disagree.  If it weren't for *my* views, my profile would have none at all.  And that's just depressing.  Are you trying to drive me back to the bottle?  Is that it?  You know my liver can't handle it.  Why don't you just shove the knife into my heart, you monster?

Comment: :) I'll buy you a pint if we ever meet.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with this. One work around is to just use the 'messages' (envelope icon) link, which goes to the recent activity page. This lets you see your recent history without incrementing the view count.

Comment: Yeah - but there's still useful information on the profile page tabs, like the overall list of how many of each type of badge I have, etc... I want to be able to go to the profile page without feeling like I'm unrealistically adding to the views.

Comment: Oh, the glory days of the envelope... I hope it comes back for April 1st or something.