# Can we have "new functionality" icons?

Tags: feature-request, help, feature-list

The meta site produces a bunch of great suggestions, many of which get implemented.

Take the narcissism question, for example... [Can "user profile views" NOT include narcissism please?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12766/can-user-profile-views-not-include-narcissism-please)

My guess is that some people (particularly those who don't frequent meta) won't realise when a piece of functionality has changed. So I'd like to see some sort of an indicator appear for a while (week? month?) to say "something has changed here, click here to find out what", with a link back to the relevant question, or FAQ entry, etc, etc...

Rob

Comment: [I support this idea.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77025/can-we-have-a-notification-for-new-features-please)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just subscribe to the [feed for the status-completed tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/status-completed)

Comment: You only see this when you are on meta, though. And most users aren't.

Comment: +1 I'm going to write a Safari Extension for this.

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we need that for **every** change, but it would definitely be good for some of the changes.

The narcissism question you referenced, doesn't really need to be brought to most users attention. Most users will probably never even realize that it has changed.

Any change where users have grown accustomed to how it used to work, and the new change is significantly different, should be referenced. For example [-5 rep for getting a down-vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the changes are likely not incredibly-noticeable. It would be annoying to have alerts for those. But if anything substantial happened, I'd definitely like to know about it :)

Comment: Well, I think if there was various littering of links to help pages, where Jeff (et al), then people could click on things to see information about how those things are calculated, and perhaps if the page has changed recently, the link could be indicated in different way or something.

Answer (score 0):

How about turning the build number at the bottom of the page into a link to the new features/changes meta article which I can never find?