# Does profile view increases on visiting my own profile?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does “user profile views” include narcissism?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12744/does-user-profile-views-include-narcissism)
>   [Can “user profile views” NOT include narcissism please?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12766/can-user-profile-views-not-include-narcissism-please)

Recently I noticed my profile view is increasing fast. It's about 10-15 view per day. I am sure that my answers are not that great that people will come to see who I am. So why this increase?

One thing I'm doing recently is, improving my 0-voted answers and removing my low quality answers. For this I have to visit my profile. Does this action increasing my profile view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, it does not increase! I've tested that!

Is useful to give you a "feedback" on the amount of users that have visited your profile.

Answer (score 1):

**No, It dont** increases with your on views. When your profile view count is increasing it means users are visiting you.