# Exclude self views from profile views

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, views

As I understand it from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122169/does-the-number-of-views-on-an-so-question-exclude-my-own-views); the number of profile views recorded in the profile includes views by the owner of the profile*. I would like to request that it excludes self views.

I recognise that the number of people who viewed your profile is hardly important but if it includes a (presumably huge and unknown) number of my own views then I’m not sure what significance to assign this number.

Clearly it would be impractical to store and search all the IPs to make this unique views, or even to preclude all IPs ever used by the profile owner. All I'd request is that if the viewer is logged in as the profile owner it doesn't count as a view.

*I think under the same cache for 10 minutes then discard rule.

Comment: Richard I honestly thought self views were not included, I had tested this.. As I would notice view changes and wanted to check if it was other people looking or my own browser

Comment: I *think* that its a cashed IPs thing, so if you look at your profile several times over a short period it doesn't count. Makes it really difficult to test. I also tested it over a long time, but who knows if it *actually* was me, or was annother viewer

Comment: hm, yes I was wondering about that... it means question and profile views are irrelevant for users who visit both often., hm I visit my profile all the time to look things up from my history, I cannot edit your post Richard, Cache is spelt cache, not cashe, is pronounced cashe though

Comment: [Apparently this already happens](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12766/can-user-profile-views-not-include-narcissism-please). Do you have evidence otherwise?

Comment: @CodyGray Only my own imperfect testing (without knowing the caching time its difficult to test conclusively) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122169/does-the-number-of-views-on-an-so-question-exclude-my-own-views) link. If it indeed already is like this (1) awesome (2) I did not expect 200 people to view my profile! and (3) I need to post a new answer to the linked question

Comment: @RichardTingle caching, caching please man

Comment: Hmm, [the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122169/does-the-number-of-views-on-an-so-question-exclude-my-own-views) you posted in the question and in your last comment talks about views on *questions*. This question is about views on your *profile page*. Not the same thing.

Comment: sorry Richard, hey see this answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12744/does-user-profile-views-include-narcissism/12745#12745 I agree with this, as I've tried this too

Comment: @CodyGray O hell, you're right, I picked it out of the "Questions that may already have your answer" box and was already primed to think it was a related question

Comment: @Yve Voting to close for the time being but i'll probably delete

Comment: @RichardTingle I can you +1 anyway, it wasn't a bad question, we have unearthed answers!! maybe you should leave it, as I've been told duplicates can help lead people to answers through search results ;)

Comment: @Yve Maybe you're right, I'll self answer with "You're being a fool" or something to that meaning

Comment: @RichardTingle you are being way too hard on yourself, seriously, go through my posts, My questions by vote order and look, I have a rep of over 1000 just now, I really don't know how... go have a laugh and browse my profile hahahahhahahaha you will feel so much better, I have broken every rule in the book, including dobbing on moderators to themselves.. have a look at my flags here OMG

Comment: @Yve Reporting a moderator to themselves is pretty impressive

Comment: @RichardTingle I know!!! I get along well with him now, I added it to my profile just now,. I know how people feel when they feel they've made a blunder, and man have I made some doosies.. seriously some of my questions on meta have so many votes, with a net vote of like +2, as I am so .. is complicated the right word to use??? it's kind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After investigation (thanks Yve and Cody Grey) this is already the case; as per [Can "user profile views" NOT include narcissism please?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12766/can-user-profile-views-not-include-narcissism-please). Also relevant [Does "user profile views" include narcissism?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12744/does-user-profile-views-include-narcissism/12745#12745)

**Self views do not increase your 'profile views' count**