# New Badges Proposal

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New badge proposal based on number of profile views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6578/new-badge-proposal-based-on-number-of-profile-views)

How About to add 2 badges wich is based on your profile views

> - Silver  - Popular - 100 views
> - Golden  - Celebrity - 500 views

P.S. Just fun badges like Enthusiast or Epic

Comment: Ok now you have 1 view in your profile page.........

Comment: Besides, the thresholds are far to low. I'm not that interesting and with these numbers I would have been a Celebrity (I'm not even popular).

Comment: In this case we need a Platine badge for Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can imagine all badge hunters to change their avatar image to something obnoxious or a half-nude woman just to increase profile-clicks. In short: I find it a bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

Badges are meant to encourage positive behavior.  While getting people to view your profile is not negative it is not really positive either.  Sometimes, users who create poor content get a lot of profile views, and we don't want to grant them badges because of that.   I recommend against these badges.