# Are there any reputation, badges or any privileges based on profile views?

Tags: discussion

I didn't see anything regarding that.

I think that SE won't provide the number of profile views without any purpose.

Is there anything can be gained by the increase in no. of profile views?

Comment: "*is there anything to be gained*" - nothing but your own vanity, I'm afraid. =)

Comment: That's just another piece of information without any "real" use. No different than the user's name or age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is no any reputation, badge or privileges based on profile views.

There was [a proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6578/187824) for badge based on profile views which was declined.