# Badge of the beast (somewhat silly)

Tags: discussion, badges, fun, badge-request

Today I happened to reach 666 reputation on StackOverflow.

So if there were a "Badge of the beast" I'd won it. What do you think about it? Too silly?

Comment: But if I had 7 reputation, would I have more then you'ld ever have, as you can repeat 6 as many times as you want, you never get 7 (God's number)?

Comment: You can't own the water...God owns the water...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I want the **1337 badge**!!!

[image: Leet Me!]

Comment: You need 94 points to reach it (1337-1243). We could help, but has to be timed in order to be effective. And it will need 3 downvotes too

Comment: Ha, I'm totally ok with using my downvotes to get my rep to a fun number for a screenshots.

Comment: 14 to go as I see :)

Comment: Ha, thanks!  Careful, bad voting patterns may result in them getting removed.

Comment: I'm going to keep interfering by upvoting and removing my upvote repeatedly.

Comment: Well, I'll jsut make sure to downvote you when I need to adjust my rep.

Comment: 1337  LOLCats rocks.

Comment: Or, you could keep your downvotes, and change the value with firebug...

Comment: http://statestreetgang.net/post/2008/09/Im-so-leet.aspx

Comment: Ha, I can give myself rep too! Yay for accepting answers.

Comment: Where is that badge service?

Comment: +1, congratulations. Long live the power of the community!

Comment: Ha, thanks.  This also taught me to be more liberal with my upvotes on meta.  We are all friends here.

Comment: If you are *unlucky*, you can achieve it twice! :)

Comment: @Justin: Think positive, give bountys to get to fun numbers (well, downvotes are still needed for fine tuning...)

Comment: Bounties are a good way to do rep-tweaking (@kriss)

Answer (score 12):

Yes, that is really too silly.

Comment: Now, that's a short answer I can get behind.

Comment: I had a feeling you would.

Comment: I should really get to work instead of trolling the StackOverflows.

Answer (score 6):

Private badges. Track your own metrics and create your badge images, then post them in your description area and count them. Same as [TheTXI](http://ponyoverflow.com) does.

**Edit:** [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3167/badge-for-winning-your-own-bounty/6984#6984).

[image]

Comment: I'm lazy, I have a job, the Sun shines. Why bother myself? ;)

Comment: Custom badges rock.

Comment: Beside the joke, If you can provide verifiable metrics of your deeds, it should count as same as any standard badge. You know the tale with Mohammed and the Mountain?

Comment: @TheTXI: and the good thing is, they are displayed at the top of your user page, whereas the standard badges are at the bottom :)

Comment: There's an easier way of making your own badges and it requires no graphics programs.

Comment: But I love Paintbrush!

Answer (score 4):

Only if I get one when I hit 666 bronze badges.

Otherwise, too silly.

Comment: I actually think that would be worth a Beast badge. But then I wonder what badge you would get at 666 silver- or gold badges...

Comment: "Neighbors of the Beast"

Comment: @kd304: [that's 667](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0366758/trivia?tr0718270).

Answer (score 3):

VI VI VI

The editor of the Beast.

Answer (score 2):

I want a 'Damien' badge

Answer (score 2):

But the number of the Beast is 616.

Comment: and what happens if you turn my current rep score upside down? WHERES BY BADGE

Comment: Mine is 666, I have an Iron-Maiden-based culture

Comment: But there is no Beast.

Answer (score 0):

What about a Answer to Life the Universe and Everything badge? (42)

Comment: Jon Skeet already owns that badge and he's not giving it up.

Comment: Jon Skeet *knows* the answer, or Jon Skeet *is* the answer?

Comment: Yes           .