# Badges for Power-of-Two reputation scores

Tags: discussion, reputation, badge-request

I just managed to get a score of 1024 = 2 ** 10. Seeing that number I spontaniously thought that there should be a badge for power of two's. Not every power of two, but 1024 is definitly a popular one, as it is 1kb. The next could be 2 ** 16 = 65'536.

Ironically, creating a meta-account to post this proposition here gave me 100 reputation and destroyed my nixe 1024 score ;)

Comment: wouldn't a badge for [1337 reputation](http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?pid=3873882&l=b66f8c08db&id=660044165) be better?

Comment: @Eric [This has already been proposed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7741/badge-of-the-beast-somewhat-silly) `:P`

Comment: Yeah, but I think a power-of two badge would fit in much better with stackoverflow than a devil badge. That may fit in well with metalunited.com or something...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The point of badges is to encourage good behavior, not random chance. Take a screenshot, throw a party, do what you must to celebrate the occasion (I know I did a dance when I hit 2999 reputation exactly), but there's no reason the system has to reward you for something that's simply chance or numeric manipulation. There's nothing good encouraged by hitting a specific number.

Numeric manipulation is the primary reason that this badge would actually be a bad idea. People who are nearing the number of desire would use crafty downvotes and other measures to ensure that they get at the exact number they want, which is casting votes on the motivation of getting reputation to a specific level rather than to mark the usefulness (or lack thereof) of posts.

Comment: *I know I did a dance when I hit 2999 reputation exactly* Pictures or it didn't happen.

Comment: @perbert ...of the reputation hit, or the dance?

Comment: I'm good, I believe you.  You can keep the dance unpublished.

Answer (score 4):

I'm opposed because it would take hours of trickery to get done ("I need six downvotes to come back to 65535") without any additional value to neither the site, nor the user.

Comment: Yes, I meant an exact power of two.

Comment: So if it only took a few minutes of trickery, that would be OK? :P

Comment: @Aarobot hey, it can be *damn* difficult to gather a few dozen downvotes if you miss the mark and get upvoted a few times too often! And if you totally miss it, the ultimate measure will be writing something so abysmal that it will get flagged as spam. Granted, it would make for great entertainment every time a respected member of the community reaches the threshold and suddenly starts spewing out crap :D

Comment: Instead of knocking yourself with a -100 for spam, post a bounty. If you're in the middle of a bounty, already, just wait for it to run out and increment the cost to accomodate the extra upvotes you got while waiting for said expiration.

Comment: Or you could just keep giving other people downvotes until you get where you want.  That would be much quicker, and if you downvote questions you can earn the Electorate badge while you're at it!

Comment: @Aarobot grand idea! This badge really has potential. :D