# A bounty worth 0 reputation

Tags: support, bounties

[Is there a way to diff files from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451694/is-there-a-way-to-diff-files-from-c/1472965#1472965)

How is it possible? It also looks like the user has awarded a bounty himself. Is it because two accounts were merged?

Comment: Read the [Bounty FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067). To quote: "Can I award a bounty to my own answer?" "Yes, but you do not receive the reputation that was allocated to the bounty. These answers display +0, “this answer has been awarded bounty worth 0 reputation”."

Comment: Interesting catch.

Comment: @Grace, the answer in question was posted in Sep 2009. Two months earlier, you [couldn't accept your own answer for bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3167/badge-for-winning-your-own-bounty/3170#3170). I'm not sure when the rule change was, still looking into that.

Comment: @Popular Well, I can't speak for what people were talking about in July, but [the original bounty announcement](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/reputation-bounty-for-unanswered-questions/) from January 2009 says you can accept your own answer and establishes that the reputation is lost. So it's well within the capacity of the system to have had this rule in effect on Sep 2009. As to whether there was a period in which bounties could no longer be self-accepted, well, that's a question for a historian.

Comment: @Grace, gasp!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can award a bounty to yourself, but you don't get any of the rep.  It's lost forever.