# Please list bounties a user both participated in and won

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, bounties

I just thought of something that might be nice. How about you, in the very least, list bounties won somewhere on your profile? Perhaps this should even be public information. I'd like to see:

- Questions I've answered that have or have had bounties on them;
- Which of those I won;
- Links to those questions/answers;
- Bounties I've started;
- Total rep gained from bounties;
- Total rep spent on bounties.

Comment: I have a terrible suspicion that this might be somewhat... "incriminating" for me. Honestly, I'm just trying to help people! Good suggestion though, +1

Answer (score 11):

I'm for it, because I can't think of reason this information *shouldn't* be available.  On a related note, why isn't there a Bounty Hunter badge?  I don't even care what it does, it just seems like the most obvious badge name ever.

Comment: It's been suggested on UserVoice AT LEAST once and I thought the powers that be liked the idea, it just never came to be (to this point at least)

Answer (score 3):

Although I have never once participated in the bounty system in any way, I think this would be an interesting set of stats to see on other users, but then again I'm a stat fanatic. It's probably a good thing I am not a fan of baseball.

Comment: That's what I can do with the datadumps: stackoverflow-reference.com.  I'll have all sorts of crazy stats like Tag-Independent Adjusted Upvotes and Value Over Replacement Answer!

Comment: @Pesto - Can you make up trading cards too? With pictures on the front and states on the back!?

Comment: I smell a business plan forming.

Comment: **I THOUGHT OF IT FIRST!  STAY BACK, IT'S MINE!**

Answer (score 2):

It's a good idea. You list various options of features, and it has positive overall value to add to the site.

Even better if this system could be retroactive.

Answer (score 2):

Good idea. Then we can see Marc Gravell for the scurrilous bounty hunter he truly is :)

Comment: damn, my secret is out... still; I'm holding out for the Fett badge ;-p