# More tag badges

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, badge-request, tag-badges

I think it would help spur more niche activity if there were more niche tag badges.

Tag badges could be created based on some criteria, like 1000 questions or 1000 answers or something that would require at least some level of activity.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This already happens.  Earn 400 upvotes for *any* tag, and you will be awarded a silver badge for that tag, even if the badge doesn't exist yet.  Earn 1000 upvotes and you will be awarded a gold badge.

1000 questions or 1000 answers alone isn't good enough, because that would give you the ability to award the badge to yourself and in effect encourage you to spam those tags.  Using votes puts at least some emphasis on quality as well.

Comment: How did I miss that? That's even better than my idea (although I like having different levels)

Comment: Thanks for the info, there should probably be an explanation of this on the tag-badges page.

Comment: @Lance - there is. See the Legend on the tag page - http://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags

Comment: How did I miss seeing that there are two tabs on the badges page? I'd been wondering where all the tag badges went!

Answer (score 2):

I believe tag badges are already automatically created once someone has reached 400 upvotes in a given tag.  I'm trying to dig up a reference to back this up, but I'm certain that's the case...

EDIT:  Here's the reference:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/specialist-badge-implemented/

Scroll halfway down for Jeff's post:

> Jeff Atwood says: February 17th, 2009
> at 11:06 am
>
> > *Ruby doesn’t get a badge? No fair.*
>
> *Any* tag gets a badge dynamically created when it reaches the threshold
> of 400 by at least one user.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it would be useful for Jeff and the team to develop an automatic tag badge system that would create a new badge when certain tags go over a certain question threshold (100 questions would create a bronze badge category, 500 would create a silver badge category, and 1000 would create the gold level category).

**Edit** Disregard this. Apparently they already give the badges automatically (even if a badge doesn't exist yet) if you score enough upvotes.

Comment: you haven't actually ever used Stack Overflow, have you?

Comment: Jeff Atwood: Funnily enough the same day I say this I automatically get awarded a "Discussion" badge.