# Separate "status-completed" from "already works that way" suggestions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, meta

I'm following the "status-completed" tag on MetaSO to see what changes are going in.  Sometimes I see questions which request something which already exists (like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8126/more-tag-badges), for example), and they get tagged "status-completed".  This is a little misleading, since you didn't actually implement/change/complete anything.  Maybe another status-* badge can be used?  Either "status-bydesign" or a new one (I can't think of a good name for it though.. maybe "status-alreadythere"?).

Comment: Maybe Jeff is psychic and implemented these features in anticipation of their future requests?

Comment: We could start marking these as 'status-bydesign' instead, since they were designed that way.  The problem here is that this is like telling the asker, "No, we won't fix it."

Comment: @Joel: My heart breaks for them.

Comment: Meta-Meta debate. Jeff is going explode! :)

Comment: StackOverflow is in the business of building and maintaining a community. That means treating all users as if they really matter all the time. Especially if they care enough to post to meta.

Comment: @Joel I like the subtle "treating them *as if* they really matter" (italics mine) =P

Comment: @kip, the problem with "status-alreadythere" is that it hints of "Status-RTFM" which we don't want to encourage. This way, you can't tell the difference between something that was requested BEFORE it was implemented, and something that was requested AFTER it was implemented. We don't want to be adding tags that just make people look dim.

Comment: @devinb i think "status-bydesign" also hints of "status-RTFM", but it is in use.  in the cases i've seen, judging by the comments, people don't seem to be offended by answers saying "you can already do this"

Comment: Wasn't there a bug (or feature) where people were answering questions before they were asked? If so, isn't this an extension of it?

Answer (score 1):

Status-Completed represents the fact that this 'feature request' has been implemented and it doesn't matter *when* it was implemented. The fact remains that what the person has requested is already available to them. They should be delighted!

Status-bydesign means that what has been reported as a bug was in fact a particular choice by the designers and that they will not be changing that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

`Status-alreadythere` would only be equivalent to `status-RTFM` if the feature were not only coded but also documented.