# Badge for bounties offered?

Tags: feature-request, badges, bounties, badge-request

Would it be worth to to add a badge for offering a certain amount of rep over time (say 1000) towards bounties? It could be called the `Sheriff` badge.

This sounds like a good idea to me now but I've been drinking.

#### Update:

With the [introduction of the new bounty system](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/), this request has become relevant again! Any other thoughts?

Comment: Please share with the rest of the group what you've been drinking.

Comment: Must be the colour scheme...

Comment: lol - this doesn't seem as good of an idea as it did when I posted it... but as for what I was drinking: Crown Reserve

Comment: Is that like Crown Solo? Crown Gloss?

Comment: @Marc - haha, somehow I never noticed that comment, but it's [Crown Royal Whisky](http://www.crownroyal.com/)

Comment: Beer here, and it doesn't seem like a good idea. I'll keep trying other combinations and let you know how it goes. (NB: Its 2 AM here at the time of this writing)

Comment: Curiously, [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/bounty-hunter-badges) was marked `[status-completed]` because of the [four new bounty badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/bounty-hunter-badges/59064#59064), even though they're really closer to completing this request.

Comment: Shameless plug to: [How about a bronze badge for collecting your first bounty?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68620/how-about-a-bronze-badge-for-collecting-your-first-bounty)

Comment: I've just found a [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559676/yihui-xie?tab=bounties&sort=offered) who currently has 22k rep and offered already astonishing 37650 rep in 81 bounties. Why does he not get a badge already?

Answer (score 34):

I think more importantly would be an badge for winning that much rep through bounties. Say bronze if you won your first bounty, silver for at least 1000 rep through bounties and gold for 5000 or so. And yes, I also think a badge for giving bounties could be a good thing. I don't think someone easily throw away his hard-earned reputation for a bounty only to win a badge. So such an badge wouldn't hurt the system.

Comment: exactly what I would've said if I'd seen the question sooner :)

Comment: Especially if the badge is a bit higher for offering. 1k is only two 500 bounties.

Comment: It could be a count of bounties rather than a sum, e.g. 1=bronze, 10=silver, 40=gold.

Answer (score 23):

Offering a bounty means you are willing to give up some reputation for the good of the community, as all reasons eventually lead to better content or rewarding existing good content.

The act of *offering* is what matters most in my opinion, not manually awarding and we already got [investor](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/219/investor) badge which is a good start - but I would like to see silver and gold badges as well.

- **Philanthropist** - Silver badge. *Offered at least 5 bounties worth total of at least 1000 reputation*.
- **Good Samaritan** - Gold badge. *Offered at least 50 bounties worth total of at least 5000 reputation*.

The limitations will protect the badges from gaming by offering minimum amount of reputation.

Edit: just noticed there is already pending feature request:
[Can we have a badge called "big spender" or "seeder"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40090/can-we-have-a-badge-called-big-spender-or-seeder)

Comment: why should someone who has spent `10x500=5000` be penalized for not spending his rep in chunks of `50`? Was that put in just to prevent gaming? If so, I would call the guy who throws away 5000 rep for a badge the king among fools.

Comment: @yoda yes indeed, this is to protect against gaming. Of course it's not perfect, one with 30K rep for example don't really mind losing a petty 5000 no matter how they are spent but still..

Comment: I suppose it isn't that outrageous a requirement as it seemed at first... Oh well. I'm not very hopeful for the team implementing this, but I'm willing to be surprised.

Comment: @yoda same here but we do see new badges from time to time and I think the names are pretty cool. Time will tell! :)

Comment: I'd probably switch the two names... philanthropist definitely trumps the other in terms of perception.

Comment: @yoda fine by me - but let's first have this approved, lol..

Comment: Gold badge for 50 bounties...it's very hard....Can't we decrease it?

Comment: @Somnath nope, Gold badges should be really hard to earn on purpose.. kind of playing games in the Insane mode or its equivalent. ;)

Comment: I'd definitely swap the names around and maybe remove the minimum amount of bounties, in favour of the total reputation offered.

Answer (score 8):

Badges should be encouraging good behavior. It is still up for debate whether or not offering bounties counts as "good behavior" especially when you can just start making bounties for simple questions and throwing minimum rep at it.

I think a badge for winning bounties is a lot more logical than for offering up bounties.

Comment: Why the tumbleweed-badge? Is asking a question so particular special that nobody is interested in a "good behaviour" that needs badge-support?

Comment: @Mnemetnth, I believe the `tumbleweed` is an exception to the rule, and is more of a "consolation prize", but I agree with TheTXI, generally badges are in place to encourage desired behavior.

Comment: Doesn't offering bounties for questions you *really* want answered count as desired behavior?  If the threshold is cumulative on rep amount and not the number of questions, then there's disadvantage to always offering the minimum.

Answer (score 8):

Awarding a badge for offering bounties is a great way to promote this feature and help make users aware of it, as well as to encourage them to use this feature to help promote great questions.

However, I'm not 100% convinced that the name of the badge fits the actions, considering we already have existing badges named after peace officers and law enforcement that are awarded for flagging unwanted content.

As far as badge names go, I really like [Plutocrat](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plutocrat) as a name for the badge. A plutocrat is:

> someone who rules by virtue of his or her wealth.

Does a huge bounty not determine what questions get the most attention in the StackExchange network? Is this not a form of ruling by virtue of one's reputational wealth?

I also like [Tycoon](http://thesaurus.com/browse/tycoon):

> person who has a lot of money, power.

**Below are reasons why "Sheriff" may not be the best name for a bounty badge:**

While I can definitely see the correlation between "Sheriff" badge and offering a "bounty", I feel like that could be confused with the two badges that are awarded to those who raise helpful flags.

Currently, the [Citizen Patrol](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/8/citizen-patrol) badge is awarded to a user who, for the first time, flags a post. The [Deputy](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1002/deputy) badge is awarded for raising 80 helpful flags, and the [Marshal](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1298/marshal) badge is awarded for raising 500 helpful flags. When we look at these three badges, it's clear that we're comparing apples to apples but in varying quantities.

The proposed Sheriff badge would likely be confused with other badges intended to recognize  volunteers who help keep the site clean, free of spam, and who alert diamond moderators of potential problems. Awarding bounties, on the other hand, is more closely related to awarding the accepted answer than it is to blowing the whistle on a spammer.

Since we already have some badges for those who offer and award bounties, we should look to those existing badges when deriving inspiration for naming a new badge.

**Bounty Badges:**

The current badges awarded for bounties are the [Altruist](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/222/altruist), [Benefactor](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/221/benefactor), [Investor](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/219/investor), and [Promoter](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/220/promoter), with the first two badges being awarded for awarding bounties and the latter two badges being awarded for offering bounties.

Therefore, with this logic, it stands to reason that a question about a badge awarded to individuals who offer bounties over time should have a name that fits within the same categories as other existing badges related to offering bounties on questions.

Investor and Promoter are those two existing badges related to bounty offerings. Here are the synonyms for those:

**Investor:**

From [Thesaurus.com on investor](http://thesaurus.com/browse/investor):

> a financier
>
> Synonyms: backer, banker, capitalist, lender, shareholder, stockholder, venture capitalist

From [Thesaurus.com on promoter](http://thesaurus.com/browse/promoter):

**Promoter:**

> a supporter
>
> Synonyms: advertiser, advocate, ally, backer, booster, endorser, follower, organizer, publicist, sponsor

Tycoon and Plutocrat were words that are more closely related to investor, and are words I found on the same page. These are not names we've used before on badges. However, I noticed that promoter has two synonyms for two badges that we award for sharing links to questions, the [Booster](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/261/booster) badge and the elusive [Publicist](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/262/publicist) badge. Therefore, my logic may be somewhat flawed in ruling out "Sheriff" as the name for the badge.

Still, if we are going to promote the creation of this bounty badge, I'd be interested to see a unique name chosen that helps separate it from other types of badges that are awarded for unrelated activities and that emphasize wealth or sharing of wealth.

Comment: It's worth noting this [feature-request] predates all of the 4 bounty badges you listed...with that in mind, adding a badge for bounties seems redundant at this point anyway.

Comment: Just curious, why would you say it's redundant? What am I missing?

Comment: The purpose of adding a badge was to encourage bounties...we've done that via 4 additional badges *specifically* for that since this request, and bounty activity increased as a result.

Comment: Makes sense. You have enough on your plate anyway, so why waste time on things that pay tiny dividends. ;)  Still, if you do implement another badge, we've got the names picked out.

Comment: Yup yup, it's not so much dev time...badges are quick to implement, it's the time researching to see if they're needed that's the time sink.  In this case though since it's promoting the *exact* same action, a duplicate badge isn't warranted...if you look at the badge list, we don't duplicate for the same exact behavior (it'd be better to make another badge more appealing in that case, or add a silver/gold level, etc.)  That being said, a higher level badge for bounties is a possibility, but I'm pretty sure that isn't needed, yet anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Using the [Top Investors](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65683/top-investors) query written by [Jeremy Banks](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/6321) on the data explorer I've listed the amount of people on Stack Overflow who would are currently eligible for the proposed badges:

- 13 users have invested at least 5000 (0 users on sister sites Server Fault & Super User)
- 73 users have invested at least 2500
- 414 users have invested at least 1000
- 1404 users have invested at least 500

Gold badges on Stack Overflow range hugely from 25,691 users with the 'Famous Question' badge to the 79 users who have earned a Legendary badge.

Answer (score 6):

1. I absolutely encourage posting while drunk. +1 to you.
2. And (soberly, sadly) I'm not sure this would be the best idea -- you could get folks offering up easy 100 points on questions they haven't selected an answer to just to get this badge. Bounties are meant to be sort of a last resort incentivizer, not something that we want everybody to aspire to.

Comment: +1, although I see rep as more of an incentive than badges - I wouldn't offer my rep like that just to get a badge

Comment: Oh I probably would.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the goal of the bounty system is to help users to provide additional incentive to a question they would really like an answer to. Therefore, I do not believe is this a feature that needs any additional encouragement placed on it, as a badge would do. Essentially badges should be awarded to users who are providing services or behavior that the system needs. I don't think that offering bounties falls into the category of a behavior the system needs. Its an available feature, but its available for you, not the system. Voting is something the system needs to function, so there are badges related to voting. The system needs editors, flaggers and retaggers; SO would be lesser without them. I do not think SO would be lesser if no one ever offered another bounty.

Comment: I've answered (and won) several bounty questions (that I previously missed due to having to sleep / work / etc occasionally). Those users got acceptable answers to their problem; so while I agree we don't need a badge for it, offering bounties does, IMO, contribute to the site. Ergo, SO would be lesser without them.

Comment: @Marc - I was just thinking that while reading this answer. For one thing, bounties (even pointless ones, e.g. the one this question) have encouraged good answers such as this one which wouldn't have been posted if the bounty were not offered

Comment: @Marc, I see your point, but I'm still of the mind that the benefit to SO is less, and the OP already is gaining a reward, they've received an answer to something they really needed an answer to, so I don't think it needs to be additionally incentivised. If the badge were for multiple bounties that did not result in an accepted answer, similar to the `tumbleweed` badge, I could maybe get behind that as a "consolation prize".

Answer (score 5):

I just won my first bounty... and was about to ask why there are no bounty related badges... I was hoping to get a `boba fett` badge.  But reading TheTXI's answer I can see the logic in *not* offering a badge for offering a bounty.

So... come on Jeff, add a `status-?` tag so we know where you stand on this...

Answer (score 2):

I would like to see badges for placing bounty in unanswered questions, following which the question receives positive score answer(s), and finally one such answer is offered the bounty.

- For 10 such actions, a silver badge
- For 50 such actions, a gold badge

The names can be anything like Philanthropist (which someone suggested already here), Patron, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with TheTXI here. The theory of this seems nice, but the reality of it wouldn't work. Think about it, people just randomly tossing rep in bounties on random questions for a badge. It would throw a fork into the reputation and moderation system - people gaining rep left and right.

As a much better alternative to this, how about getting a badge when you *win* a certain amount of rep in bounties.

This way, you still need to uphold high-quality answers to get a bounty, and bounties will remain *special* because there won't be too many going on at a time.

You would get rewarded with a badge when people have found you so helpful, you gained X extra rep in bounties from them.