# Can we have a badge called "big spender" or "seeder"?

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

If someone gives away lot of his reputation points for his questions (using bounties) he should get the badge "big spender" or "seeder" or "motivator".

Comment: `[Venture Capitalist]`!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Badge for bounties offered?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14421/badge-for-bounties-offered)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I like the <kbd>[venture capitalist]</kbd> as mentioned by ~quack.

The rules might need to be something around gave more then 300 reputation on more then 3 bounty questions however, otherwise it will be easily abused.

The flip side is people not understanding bounties, especially the loss of ability to accept an answer in future if the bounty expires. This may be a reason not to introduce the badge.

Comment: The latter is a UI problem IMO. People should be told this clearly when starting the bounty ("Your bounty will expire in seven days. If you let your bounty expire, you will not be able to accept an answer afterwards. Are you sure you want to start a bounty?")

Comment: doesn't it lock the accepted answer regardless?  "Your bounty will expire in seven days. If you let your bounty expire, you will not be able to accept an answer afterwards.  If you accept an answer before the bounty expires, you will not be able to unaccept the answer in the future.  Are you *really* sure you want to start a bounty?  *Really, really sure?* "

Comment: No it doesn't. If no answer qualifies and you don't select one you can never accept an answer on the question even if there is one.

Comment: no, i meant if *you* accept an answer (before bounty expiration), or if an answer is *autoaccepted* -- regardless, if an answer is accepted, it's locked and you can't change it, and if an answer is *not* accepted, it's locked and you can't change it.  or am i misunderstanding?

Comment: Correct on the first part. On the second part if no answer is accepted the question is locked and you can never select an answer. Actually, your understanding is correct and I misunderstood your initial explanation.

Answer (score 11):

In the spirit of *"badges are to encourage good behavior,"* I don't think that bounties should be arbitrarily encouraged. **They serve a *very specific* purpose.** If there was a significant increase in the number of so-called *"featured"* questions, that would detract from those that actually need it.

According to the podcasts, bounties are only supposed to be used *after* you **put the effort into getting the question answered yourself**. If you don't get an immediate answer, you are expected to improve, clarify, and document your continued efforts...first. That's why there is a 2-day waiting period to add bounties.

I don't think we should be encouraging bounties as an end-goal of giving away reputation or earning accolades.

Comment: +1 When a bounty is started it should show a bounty agreement screen that lists the above plus a description of what happens if the bounty should expire. Then again I can't remember if it does already do this.

Comment: @Diago: Should they enable the "Continue" button only after you've scrolled down to the bottom? :)

Comment: @Fearless. Lolz. Yeah that would make it even more detailed.

Comment: how about awarding the badge after the person has accepted an answer to a bounty question? and many badges seem to be awarded for activities that could be considered 'good behaviour' - but can just be 'played', like the badge for editing your own question or comment...

Comment: Giving away your reputation points to someone who might have put a lot of effort and even time can be considered as good behavior I would say.

Comment: Additionally when you put your reputation on a unanswered question in most cases the quality of the anwsers improve greatly and become much more detailed. This serves us all and our posterity!!

Comment: The motivation behind an answer does not matter. It is the answer that matters. We should definately encourage people to give away their reputation to people who deserve it.

Answer (score 7):

I totally support badges for people starting bounties, for the simple reason that

1. Bounties are great
2. Badges are great
3. I'm going to get one right away! (about 2,500 points spent on bounties and counting!)

Make the thresholds high enough and the danger of abuse - i.e. frivolous questions impossible to shut down because they're a bounty - will approach zero. No up-and-coming SO'an is going to spend their precious points on a silly bounty badge. And the few dedicated badge-hunters who are going to start bounties *because of the badges* I trust will be able to come up with an intelligent question - otherwise they have no business collecting badges, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I have suggested [exactly this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14421/badge-for-bounties-offered) last August and have no response as of yet... obviously +1 from me!