# How about a bronze badge for collecting your first bounty?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badge-request, bounty-badges

Does SO already have a badge that is awarded to the user for the first time he gets an accepted answer on a featured question? Should we get one?

I would suggest naming it the **Bounty Hunter** badge, of course.

Comment: Related: [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/bounty-hunter-badges). Would be a dupe if it wasn't marked `[status-completed]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, I want a bronze badge!  Please daddy.

Comment: Fill in all the fields on [your profile](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/153026) and you'll get one!

Comment: (PS: I'm **not** your daddy.)

Answer (score 6):

You already get the bounty (or 15 rep for accepted answer), isn't that reward enough?

Comment: @Tobias Having 25 people upvote your question isn't reward enough? You still get a badge for it anyway.

Comment: @karlphillip: touché. But these badges probably had to be introduced for fairness when the Altruist and Investor badges where introduced to encourage users to put bounties on other users questions. OTOH, one gets a badge for first posted answer etc, so why not? +1

Comment: @Tobias Take the Benefactor badge for instance: first bounty you manually awarded on your own question. You already receive the bounty, but you also get a badge with it. We are talking about a bronze badge. These are common and many of them are pretty easy to get. Featured questions usually take a bit more experience to answer, and I think it would be nice to receive a BRONZE badge for the first time you do it.

Comment: @karlphillip: as said, you already convinced me :)

Comment: @Tobias Thank you, mate! ;)

Comment: @karlphillip You don't get Benefactor for receiving a bounty.

Comment: @Grace What? You put 50 rep for bounty and if you answer your own question you can't have the rep back? Where does the points go to?

Comment: @karl You get Benefactor for awarding *anyone* the bounty you placed on your question. It's basically earned for actually awarding the bounty, not letting it auto-award after 7 days. As for what happens if you award yourself a bounty, the bounty is simply gone. You paid for the exposure of the question, you don't get the reputation back simply because you happened to answer it yourself. Otherwise, you could indefinitely sponsor a question on the featured tab, among other things.