# Badges for bounties

Tags: feature-request, badges, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Badge for bounties offered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14421/badge-for-bounties-offered)

I see there are bronze badges for first bounty:

- `Altruist`    First bounty you manually awarded on another person's question
- `Benefactor`  First bounty you manually awarded on your own question
- `Investor`    First bounty you offered on another person's question
- `Promoter`    First bounty you offered on your own question

But there are no silver/gold badges for giving out bounties repeatedly.

I just saw [this guy](https://stackexchange.com/users/265579/msh210?tab=reputation) that gave out bounties generously, not only on his "primary" account where he had lots of rep points to take from, but also on some of his accounts where he had not much more that the 100 points he got initially from attaching the new account to the same user withtin the SE network (because ha had >200 point on another account). This resulted in he having left only 21 points after giving a 100 point bounty! (see [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/6445/249) on Music SE).
On his biggest account where he has high rep, he has given out numerous bounties.

I think this kind of generosity should be awarded with more than a simple bronze badge for the first one.

I think Silver for giving bounties total worth of 2000 points, and gold for total of 5000.

Maybe even an additional gold badge for giving a bounty that takes you back more than 70%, which will be a big sacrifice on the account rep points.

I think maybe the silver and gold should be only for questions you don't own yourself, because this shows effort to promote other people's questions. Promoting your own questions does not need the same initiative.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145966/135505

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bounty is supposed to be an indicator of a hard/interesting/important question that needs to be answered. The way it works now, it encourages people to bounty the questions they really want to know the answer of.

If you add badges for that, some people might start adding bounties to random questions just to get the badge, and really important questions with bounties will be lost under the sea of random ones. Also you can't really be sure that bigger bounty means a more important question in this case, because someone might offer ridiculous bounties for simplest questions just for the badge.