# Add badge: 'Prize Chaser' to people chase bounties and win them

Tags: feature-request, badge-request, bounty-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bounty Hunter badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/bounty-hunter-badges)

Add a badge for person who solve bounty questions and win them, let say he gain this bronze badge if he solved   and won x bounties in x days, this is negotiable, I have seen this question:

[Badge for bounties offered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14421/badge-for-bounties-offered)

This question is a good one, and I support it, but my specific badge is not mentioned in his question, this encourage people to solve bounty questions!

Comment: Already suggested and declined.

Comment: This is a different type of badge than the one you guys are looking at.  He wants it for x number of bounties, not based on rep earned on bounties.  Not a dupe.

Comment: Yes, you are right, not a duplicate, but i have mentioned it in my question to avoid marking my question as a duplicate :(

Answer (score 4):

You already gain (partially massive) reputation points from bounties. There is no need to **further** encourage people to answer bounty questions and this is what badges are about -  encourage good behaviour.

Comment: This encourage people to keep looking on featured questions, and not go to "newest" tab without taking a look at featured tab :)

Comment: @MohammadSakherSawan but the point is why do you need to encourage that behavior?  The rep reward should be more than enough encouragement.  The idea of most badges is to teach someone the features of the site and encourage specific good behaviors.  Bounties themselves already do that.