# Map of Badges currently in use

Tags: discussion, badges

Basically, I've taken the current badges on StackOverflow, and broke them into **actions** you can perform on the site. (Posting, Editing, etc).

Once I decided on the **actions**, I gave each action a *gold*, *silver*, and *bronze* badge, and saw which badges actually fit into those categories.

This left me with a list that shows which site actions don't have certain levels of badges in them. I'm not saying that we *should* put these badges in place, I'm just giving an overview of where the disconnects are.

Enjoy!

```
Posting

 Question
  Views
   [b] Popular Question - Asked a question with 1,000 views
   [s] Notable Question - Asked a question with 2,500 views
   [g] Famous Question - Asked a question with 10,000 views

  Votes
   [b] Student - Asked first question with at least one up vote
   [b] Nice Question - Question with score of 10 or more
   [s] Good Question - Question with score of 25 or more
   [g] Great Question - Question with score of 100 or more

  Favorite
   [b]
   [s] Favorite Question - Question favorited by 25 users
   [g] Stellar Question - Question favorited by 100 users

  Tagging
   [b]
   [s] Taxonomist - Created a tag used by 50 questions
   [g]

 Answers

  Votes
   [b] Nice Answer - Answer with score of 10 or more
   [s] Good Answer - Answer with score of 25 or more
   [g] Great Answer - Answer with score of 100 or more

   [b] Teacher - Answered first question with at least one up vote
   [s] Enlightened - First answer was accepted with at least 10 up votes
   [s] Guru - Accepted answer and voted up 40 times
   [g]

  Commenting
   [b] Commentator - Left 10 comments
   [s] Pundit - Left 10 comments with a score of 5 or more
   [g] 

  Bounty
   [b] Altruist - First bounty you manually awarded on another person's question 
   [b] Benefactor - First bounty you manually awarded on your own question 
   [b] Investor - First bounty you offered on another person's question 
   [b] Promoter - First bounty you offered on your own question 
   [s]
   [g]

  Low-vote accepted answers
   [b]
   [s] Tenacious - Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total 
   [g] Unsung Hero - Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total 

Reviewing

 Voting
  [b] Supporter - First upvote
  [b] Critic - First downvote
  [s] Civic Duty - Voted 300 times
  [g] Electorate - Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

 Editing
  [b] Editor - First edit
  [s] Strunk & White - Edited 80 posts
  [g] Copy Editor - Edited 500 posts

 Retagging
  [b] Organizer - First retag
  [s]
  [g]

 Rollback
  [b] Cleanup - First rollback
  [s]
  [g]

 Flagging
  [b] Citizen Patrol - First flagged post
  [s] Deputy - Raised 80 helpful flags 
  [g] Marshal - Raised 500 helpful flags

 Deleting
  [b] Disciplined - Deleted own post with score of 3 or higher
  [b] Peer Pressure - Deleted own post with score of -3 or lower
  [s] 
  [g]

Site

 Viewing
  [b]
  [s] Enthusiast - Visited the site for 30 consecutive days
  [g] Fanatic - Visited the site each day for 100 consecutive days

 Reputation
  [b] Mortarboard - Hit the daily reputation cap for the first time
  [s] Epic - Hit the reputation cap of 50 days
  [g] Legendary - Hit the daily reputation cap on 150 days

 Membership
  [b] Autobiographer - Completed "About Me" section of user profile.
  [s] Beta - Actively participated in the Stack Overflow private beta
  [s] Yearling - Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation
  [g]


Misc
 [b] Scholar - First accepted answer on your own question
 [b] Self-Learner - Answered your own question with at least 3 up votes
 [b] Tumbleweed - Asked a question with no answers, no comments, and low views for a week
 [s] Generalist - Provided non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags
 [s] Necromancer - Answered a question more than 60 days later with a score of at least 5
 [g] Populist - Provided an answer that outscored an accepted answer with 10 votes by 2x
 [g] Reversal - Provided answer of +20 score to a question of -5 score
```

Hopefully this may be of use to someone.

Comment: Why does voting have two extra spaces?

Comment: Silver Civic Duty Badge - 300 votes. I put that in because it seems like there should be one up from that, and one down from that.

Comment: I removed one of them, as the First Downvote badge is probably a good step down from Civic duty, but I think that Electorate badge is too different to be a step up from 300 votes. If someone else think differently, feel free to edit it out.

Comment: Missing section with no representation at all: closing questions.

Comment: I think that the "rollback" badge (Cleanup) needs to go into the "edit" category in stead of in its own.

Comment: Shouldn't Reversal and Populist be mapped under Answer?

Comment: This seriously needs updating

Answer (score 9):

I filled the blanks. Bolded entries are the ones I added/modified.

## Posting

### Question

**Views**

- [b] Popular Question - Asked a question with 1,000 views
- [s] Notable Question - Asked a question with 2,500 views
- [g] Famous Question - Asked a question with 10,000 views

**Votes**

- [b] Nice Question - Question voted up 10 times
- [s] Good Question - Question voted up 25 times
- [g] Great Question - Question voted up 100 times

**Favorite**

- [b] **Favorite Question - Question favorited by 10 users**
- [s] **(Name change) Favorite Q -> Grand Question - Question favorited by 25 users**
- [g] Stellar Question - Question favorited by 100 users

**Tagging**

- [b] <strike>**Junior Taxonomist - Created a tag used by 10 questions**</strike> *I think this would just encourage abusive behavior, no badge here*
- [s] Taxonomist - Created a tag used by 50 questions
- [g] **Stellar Taxonomist - Created a tag used by 250 questions**

### Answers

**Votes**

- [b] Nice Answer - Answer voted up 10 times
- [s] Good Answer - Answer voted up 25 times
- [g] Great Answer - Answer voted up 100 times

**Commenting**

- [b] Commentator - Left 10 Comments
- [s] **Guide - Left 10 comments with 6 upvotes**
- [g] **(changed from silver to gold) Pundit - Left 10 comments with 10 upvotes**

**Bounty**

- [b] **Solver - Won a bounty. <strike>This badge can be awarded several times.</strike>**
- [s] **Consultant - Won a 550 rep bounty. This badge can be awarded several times.**
- [s] **Bounty Hunter - Won 10 bounties.**
- [g] **Boba Fett - Won 25 bounties.**

---

## Reviewing

**Voting**

- [b] Critic - First Downvote
- [s] Civic Duty - Voted 300 Times
- [g] **Outstanding Citizen - Voted 2,000 times**
- [g] Electorate - Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

**Editing**

- [b] Editor - First Edit
- [s] Strunk & White - Edited 100 entries
- [g] **Editor-in-Chief - Edited 1,000 entries**

**Retagging**

- [b] Organizer - First Retag
- [s] **Cataloger - Retagged 75 entries**
- [g] **Bibliothecary - Retagged 750 entries**

**Rollback**

- [b] Cleanup - First Rollback
- [s] *I think this would just encourage abusive behavior, no badge here*
- [g] *I think this would just encourage abusive behavior, no badge here*

**Flagging**

- [b] Citizen Patrol - First flagged post
- [s] Deputy - Raised 80 helpful flags
- [g] Marshal - Raised 500 helpful flags

**Deleting**

- [b] Disciplined - Deleted own post with score of 3 or higher
- [b] Peer Pressure - Deleted own post with score of -3 or lower
- [s] *I think this would just encourage abusive behavior, no badge here*
- [g] *I think this would just encourage abusive behavior, no badge here*

---

## Site

**Viewing**

- [b] **Loyalist - Visited the site for 7 consecutive days**
- [s] Enthusiast - Visited the site for 30 consecutive days
- [g] Fanatic - Visited the site each day for 100 consecutive days

**Reputation**

- [b] Mortarboard - Hit the daily reputation cap for the first time
- [s] Epic - Hit the reputation cap of 50 days
- [g] Legendary - Hit the daily reputation cap on 150 days

Comment: Having a tagging badge for just 10 questions will re-encourage the Taxonomist wannabes, I think (and is harder to catch by the mods if used inappropriately).  And there's *no way* meta will stand for bounty badges if they're not called Greedo/Boba Fett: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/bounty-hunter-badges :)

Comment: If it was up to me I would get rid of the taxonomist badges. But as long as there is at least one there adding more with different requirements won't increase abuse, imo

Comment: i don't like the silver bounty badge (awarded for winning a 550 rep bounty).  doesn't really fit.  make that one for winning 10 bounties, and move the gold up to 50 or 100 bounties.  (leave the name "bounty hunter" on the gold, or name the silver "Greedo" and the gold "Boba" or whatever.)

Comment: @~quack: it's CW feel free to edit =p I do think 50 bounties is too much though. Even if it's 25 I'm not sure there are any people that answered that many.

Comment: ...We don't really need to encourage commenting any more than we already do...

Comment: @Koper: fair enough.  tweaked what i thought needed tweaking.  left the silver-for-550-rep; i don't think it's necessary but i don't feel strongly enough to edit it out.  (i do think there are already a few users on SO who've hit 25 bounties, or are getting close.  someone posted a result from querying the data dump not long ago.)

Comment: Regarding "Solver": are you suggesting there should be a badge with each bounty? Regarding "Editor-in-Chief": I suggest "Galley Slave" would be a more fitting title...

Comment: @Shog I agree. I think that the **first** bounty should be rewarded, but not every time after that.

Comment: Pundit is way too easy to be a gold badge. I think the gold one should be either 25 comments with 10 upvotes or 10 comments with 25 upvotes. Also, I don't theink there should be a gold badge for retagging, because it would encourage people to retag without also cleaning up the question. Retagging is only good for a small window between 500 and 2000 rep.

Comment: I don't agree with incentivizing retags.  Way too easy to abuse.  The gold batch is basically a cookie we give to new users saying "hey, thanks for learning how to use the site."  Silver and gold levels are not necessary or helpful.