# Bounty badges need pretty names

Tags: discussion, status-completed, badges, bounty-badges

We are looking at possibly adding 4 bronze single award badges for bounty related activity:

1. First bounty created
2. First bounty accepted (not by the system)
3. First bounty created on another person's question
4. First bounty accepted on another person's question (not by the system)

Of course if we described the bounties like this on the web site I would have to answer to a meta lynch mob.

So I ask you, meta, what would you name and describe these 4 badges?

Comment: Out of curiosity, would these be awarded retroactively?

Comment: of course we always award new badges retroactively

Comment: Cool, didn't realize that was the case.

Comment: Just to clarify: are badges #2 and #4 for a *bounty-giver* accepting an answer for the bounty, or for an *answerer* having their answer accepted for the bounty?

Comment: @gnovice its for the giver not the person who answered, the person answering already got a big rep bump for the answer

Comment: Greedo and Boba Fett were suggested as bounty-related names at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/bounty-hunter-badges and Bounty Hunter at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas/1158#1158

Comment: Why do you think you need to encourage bounties?

Comment: @Neil for one only 7 or so people have the altruist badge. It's mainly about encouraging people to close the loop. Keep in mind it's only a bronze once off badge

Comment: I find the bar for these badges is too low. Too easy to achieve.

Comment: @Pekka: I guess that's why they are all bronze one-offs. I see them as [little pieces of candy](http://www.gametrailers.com/user-movie/ooo-piece-of-candy-again/178238) that help introduce people to the features of the site, just like some of the other bronze badges (Supporter, Editor, Organizer, etc.).

Comment: I've fixed the missing punctuation in the badge descriptions -- this fix should be propagated to the descriptions in the DB as well.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

*EDIT: Updated now that I understand #2 and #4 better. ;)*

1. **Promoter** - First bounty you offered on your own question
2. **Benefactor** - First bounty you *manually* awarded on your own question
3. **Investor** - First bounty you offered on another user's question
4. **Altruist** - First bounty you *manually* awarded on another user's question

Comment: Altruist is awesome ! I like all 4

Comment: I think I like this list better than mine, now that I've thought about it a bit.

Comment: These are great badge names, but not for this small an achievement. These would be fitting names for a silver or gold variant. For the bronze version, I find @Lance's suggestions the most fitting.

Comment: I dunno, with easy bronzes that have names like "Citizen Patrol", "Editor", and "Scholar", these don't sound that big.

Comment: I like your descriptions the best.

Comment: @Grace true, but that kind of closes the door for silver and bronze variations, doesn't it?

Comment: @pekka it is unlikely we will have silver or golds here -- the *real* reward for a bounty is getting an answer / reputation bonus. The bronze is the important part, to teach people how to use the system.

Comment: @Jeff yup, I can see that, and I agree there is no real need for silver and gold badges in the bounty department at this time. But you never know what role bounties will play in the future, say in 5 or 10 years' time. Badges are going to be awfully hard to rename once awarded, and these suggestions are brilliant for "advanced" levels if spending huge amounts of rep on bounties should become an actively encouraged behaviour (because people spend it on updating old answers in reference questions or whatever). But that is speculation, of course.

Comment: And the **winner** is gnovice, thanks so much!

Comment: My only slight concern is the tense used in the description string, do you think it meshes with the rest of the descriptions? We do not your the words you/your in any of the other badge descriptions

Comment: @waffles: I suppose the "you" after the bounty could be removed to fit with the format of the other badge descriptions. The phrase "your own question" should be fine, since it's used for the Self-Learner badge description.

Comment: I would change "person's" to "user's", for consistency -- we don't normally refer to users as people in other areas of the site.

Comment: @Ether: Changing it to "user's" make sense, since that is used for a few other badge descriptions. I'll update my answer, but I'm not sure if that will be enough to get the attention of those in charge of any changes.

Answer (score 8):

1. **Hopeful** - First bounty created on your own question
2. **Satisfied** - First bounty accepted on your own question (not by the system)
3. **Curious** - First bounty created on another person's question
4. **Rewarder** - First bounty accepted on another person's question (not by the system)

Comment: I actually like the antonym `hopeful` for the first bounty, we want all badges to have a positive ring

Comment: @waffles, I like that, edited in.

Comment: I think these are perfect for bronze.

Answer (score 4):

1. Bountiful - First bounty created on your own question
2. Generous - First bounty accepted on your own question (not by the system)
3. Samaritan - First bounty created on another person's question
4. Benefactor - First bounty accepted on another person's question (not by the system)

Comment: The term "Samaritan" is widely mis-used. The Good Samaritan was a famous parable because the Jews were the Samaritans sworn enemy. So calling someone a Samaritan is actually an insult, unless it's a "Good Samaritan" in which case it's... a bit less of an insult

Comment: I hesitate to even say this, but... your logic suggests that the names of all of the peoples who have ever been enemies of Jews are insulting terms.  That's a hell of a lot of peoples.  If anything, calling someone a Samaritan has essentially no meaning now, while calling them a "Good Samaritan" now is more insulting, because it implies that person, while nice and all, comes from people who are inherently not good.

Comment: What gives you the idea that calling somebody a "Samaritan" an is insult? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Good_Samaritan as far as I can see, the suggestion is off the mark *because being a Samaritan doesn't automatically mean you are a good person, it's just the name of a people*, but that doesn't make the word an insult in itself.

Answer (score 3):

1. Hard-up (but hopeful!)
2. Commissioned
3. Beat Me To It
4. Works For Me

Comment: Love suggestion for #3.

Comment: Edited based on @waffles comment!

Answer (score 2):

1. Rich
2. Collector
3. Sponsor
4. Patron

Answer (score 2):

1. Advertiser - First bounty created on your own question
2. Employer - First bounty accepted on your own question (not by the system)
3. Venture Capitalist - First bounty created on another person's question
4. Philanthropist - First bounty accepted on another person's question (not by the system)

(I liked some of the others already on this page, but I've tried to make unique ones to add to the pool)

Answer (score 2):

Famous bounty hunters:

1. Hutt - He created bounties!
2. Jango Fett - He captured the bad guys and collected bounties.
3. I, err.. Hmm....
4. Boba Fett - He inherited his father's role, correct?

Answer (score 2):

1. Desperate :-)

Answer (score 1):

I like some of each, so I created my own

1. Promoter - from [gnovice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56067/bounty-badges-need-pretty-names/56074#56074)
2. Benefactor - from [gnovice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56067/bounty-badges-need-pretty-names/56074#56074)
3. Sponsor - from [ChrisW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56067/bounty-badges-need-pretty-names/56072#56072) (or: Advocate)
4. Patron - from [ChrisW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56067/bounty-badges-need-pretty-names/56072#56072) (or: Largess)

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for Pirate related names:

1. Cabin Boy
2. First Mate
3. Navigator
4. Captain

Comment: For a *Mutiny on the Bounty* theme?

Answer (score 0):

My contribution:

1. **Leap of faith** (You are trusting the community with your rep)
2. **Worth It** (The answer is worth the cash)
3. **Investor** (Investing in someone else's question)
4. **Return on Investment** (Your investment paid off)

Answer (score 0):

I think that these would be good:

1. Sponsor
2. Thankful
3. Advocate
4. Pleased