# Why am I a benefactor?

Tags: support, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find out which question/answer awarded you the badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge)

I just got a benefactor badge. How can I find out why, given that recent activity is blank and I don't think that I've ever awarded a bounty at all, thought it might have happened in the mists of time.

Comment: Jeff stole your wallet, but wanted to say thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/badges/221/benefactor?user_id=131433

Comment: @waffles - hmmm, didn't know that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You earned it from this question: [derby.log (etc) control in a webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729566/derby-log-etc-control-in-a-webapp). You posted a 50, the target earned 100, this was under the old system, so that's a manual award rather than an auto-award.

For this kind of scenario you can always search your Reputation Graph, or if you want your own stuff just check your reputation audit. See every post where you lost reputation to a bounty, and check that you manually awarded it. This is actually one of the easier badges to figure out if you're wondering where you yourself earned it.

Or, as waffles points out in a comment... they already have badge origin support...

Comment: Insufficient use of the wayback machine.

Answer (score 3):

Clicking the "Badges" option at the top gives the following definition:

> **Benefactor** - First bounty you manually awarded on your own question

So, presumably you've awarded a bounty to someone on a question that you've asked.

I think they're new(ish?) badges looking at this [Bounty badges need pretty names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56067/bounty-badges-need-pretty-names)