# Typo in Altruist description

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling, badge-description, bounty-badges

> First bounty you manually awarded on another persons question

**person's** is missing an apostrophe.

Comment: That apostrophe certainly took a long time :)

Comment: @AsheeshR 6-8 weeks = 2 years `:p`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by Ether [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56067/bounty-badges-need-pretty-names/56074#56074), it also wouldn't hurt to change "person" to "user" to blend with the other badge descriptions.

Comment: And because the user might be a dog.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail Or a snail `;)`