# Improve wording for Altruist badge

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounty-badges, wording

Currently the wording for the Altruist badge is as follows:

> First bounty accepted on another person's question (not by the system)

I can see two problems with this:

1. It's unclear whether the badge is awarded for having a bounty awarded to you by another person *or* awarding the bounty to another person.
2. It's inconsistent with the description of its brother, the Benefactor badge, which adds to the confusion of point 1 - you would expect similar wording if the requirements were along the same lines.

Benefactor's description goes as follows:

> First bounty you manually awarded on your own question

So I suggest changing the wording for Altruist to:

> First bounty you manually awarded on another person's question

The word *manually* already implies *(not by the system)*.  This makes it clearer that you don't get the badge for answering and being awarded a bounty - which I was unsure of even though the badge was only awarded 24 times.  So really I'm asking for it to be dumbed down for others like me!

Comment: This is funny, because [gnovice's suggestion for the badge names](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56067/bounty-badges-need-pretty-names/56074#56074) includes the better wording.

Comment: This is why big firms use technical writers to edit all customer-facing text; because poor grammar and spelling is embarrassing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks all, sorted (please upvote me so community does not bump me)