# How to get the Altruist badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

The [Altruist badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399) is given to somebody who manually awards another person's question for the first time. How can I award the bounty manually? Where should I click? And how much should my bounty be?

Comment: You're right. I didn't notice the meta subdomain. How can I remove it there?

Comment: Look at: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Answer (score 1):

Note the wording in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57709/improve-wording-for-altruist-badge).  To award the bounty manually, you need to click the +50 or +100 under the check mark. The bounty size will *not* affect your ability to obtain this badge.