# Where are Bounty Hunter badges?

Tags: discussion, support, badge-request, bounty-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bounty Hunter badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/bounty-hunter-badges)

I was thinking to have Bounty Hunter Badges. But there was already feature request of [Bounty Hunter badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/bounty-hunter-badges) with High votes. And it is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). But I don't see those badges in [Badges tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges).

If feature request is implemented then it is made [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Then why Bounty Hunter badges are still not in badges tab?

Comment: See the two answers by waffles and Jeff Atwood at the bottom there.

Comment: feature request asked differently and completed differently. Can we make that feature request as [status-completed]?

Comment: @MarkTrapp: How this question can be duplicate of that question? I am discussing about that question only. Offering bounty is personal decision. At bottom there is written, Not the answer you're looking for? ask your own question

Comment: @MarkTrapp: I know much about bounty system. I am bounty hunter on SO. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178505/somnath-muluk?tab=bounties and http://stackoverflow.com/users/1045444/somnath-muluk?tab=bounties

Comment: @animuson I don't see waffles' answer to that question, was it deleted?

Comment: @Cupcake waffles == Sam Saffron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the reason this is status-completed, you have to scroll all the way down to Jeff's answer (scored -14!) for his interpretation of "completed".

Comment: But this doesn't seems to make status [status-completed]. Status can be made [status-declined]. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/bounty-hunter-badges#comment338492_1182

Comment: I agree. That's probably why his answer has the score it does.