# Have altruist, investor badges granted for each bounty

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges

I believe offering or awarding bounties for somebodies else question is really good (and rare) deed, which should be rewarded by giving a medal each time when this happen (instead of giving just one medal for a first time).

BTW. Both Altruist (2451 badges) and Investor (4901 badges) are reasonably rare for bronze badges. Actually they are more rare than some golden badges (Famous question - 48411, Fanatic - 7174, Great answer - 5814).

Comment: I would love to hear criticism associated with downvotes.

Comment: Downvotes in meta are not always a criticism of the question itself. People probably just don't agree with your request.

Comment: 2madth3: That's exactly what I meant. If they don't agree most likely they have some arguments against this idea.

Comment: @VictorRonin You mean beyond just not liking the idea? Maybe, but they might not be worth articulating beyond just not liking it--it's nothing personal. (Well, I mean, okay, technically for some people it might be, I don't know.)

Comment: worth to mention, there are [more than a few requests](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbadge-request%5D+bounty+is%3Aquestion) for bounty related badges. [One of them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1182/152859) got over 100 upvotes, but still declined..

Answer (score 12):

The reason I don't like this proposal is it doesn't serve a purpose.  The idea of most badges is to reward positive behavior and/or teach users about features of the site.

**Is rewarding this badge multiple times teaching anything?**
No - if you've done it once, you know how to post a bounty and award a bounty on a question, and you know you are allowed to do it to another user's question.

**So is it encouraging positive behavior?**
Barely - Does it make the site better when you post a bounty on someone else's question?  Not really.  It might encourage another good answers on the question, but really doesn't actually make the site better (the person that comes in and answers the question because of the bounty is the one improving the site).  But just because the bounty is there, doesn't guarantee that an answer will come.

The badges that can be awarded multiple times generally are a result of activities that contribute positively to the site constantly or each time they are awarded:

- All of the "* Question" and "* Answer" (Famous, Great, Good, Popular, etc) contribute to the site every day.
- Despite the side effects cause by badge hunters, the review badges (Steward, Reviewer, Custodian) are awarded for making the site better by reviewing posts for quality and approving edits.
- The Yearling badge encourages people to continue to come back the site and actively ask and answer questions.
- The Caucus badge encourages users to participate in elections when they come up.
- The Post Sharing Badges (Announcer, Booster, Publicist) encourage users to post links on other sites, driving traffic to Stack Exchange sites.

And lastly, I just don't see the reason why the number of times a badge was awarded needs to be a factor in changing the rules to make it more common.  If this is a legitimate reason, then why not change the rules to let more people earn the Research Assistant badge simply because it has only 80 recipients on Stack Overflow (granted, you aren't changing the criteria for awarding the badge to make it more common, just how often it is awarded to someone, but it is a similar concept).

Answer (score 6):

Awarding the Altruist badge each time you bounties someone else's question would be contrary to altruism.