# Silver Badge for multiple bounties

Tags: feature-request, badge-request, bounty-badges

I think we should start a **Donor** badge for a person who awards bounty on 5 questions of others. Ideas?

Comment: No Boba Fett???

Comment: I know bounty hunter is a long topic, but donor is of my own idea :) Isn't it worth it?

Comment: I love the idea of those badges, Donor doesn't match Bounty Hunter though, they need to kinda follow on? Like **Greedo** and **Boba Fett**, they're both Bounty Hunters from Star Wars :)

Comment: @mattytommo: Actually I'm requesting **Donor** as a follow on of **Altruist**

Comment: Ahh, I thought you meant for people who *collect* bounties. Then yeah, I agree with that.

Comment: @mattytommo: I really think that this badge is worthy to be a badge

Comment: Doesn't this mean that some robo reviewers will start **buying** badges by offering random 50 rep bounties on old questions? Much easier than approving hundreds of bad edits.

Comment: @BoPersson: We can alter the credential as bounty awarded before the question got an answer and within 3 months from the original date

Comment: @mattytommo: Is this a duplicate?

Comment: @Mojo No it isn't, I've flagged it. The duplicate in question is about ACHIEVING, not AWARDING

Comment: @mattytommo: Please post me the link which has that similar question

Comment: @MoJo It was closed because it was said to be a duplicate of this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/bounty-hunter-badges but it isn't

Comment: @mattytommo: Thats for earning a bounty, This is about awarding it

Comment: @Mojo Yeah I know, I agree with that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Maybe I'm OCD, maybe I'm just picky, but I **hate it** when badges don't come in sets (bronze, silver, gold). I think that should be the case for **all badges**.

In this instance, what about Altruist (bronze), Donor (silver) and Charity (gold).

Comment: Nice combination mate :) hope some moderators sees this seriously

Comment: @MoJo - Nothing to do with moderators. Only developers can do this.

Comment: @hims056: Can't they even state a point more soundly than we do?

Comment: @MoJo - No. Meta is also run by community.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I'd like to see a silver version of Altruist; "Donor" is a good name, though I'd have called it something like "Bountiful".

Personally, I'd make it a bit harder, though; I'd think it should be "Award at least 10 bounties (worth at least 1000 reputation) on other people's questions", but the original suggestion seems fine.

If there was to be a gold version as well, making the silver a little easier might make sense.