# How does a question go from a status-completed to status-declined?

Tags: discussion, support, meta, moderator-tags

I was thinking about proposing a Bounty Hunter badge or something similar but then went and found a few proposals already.

[One particular question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/bounty-hunter-badges) has caught my attention because of the change in statuses in the [revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/1182/revisions).

That question has been asked about 4 years ago originally and I haven't been around for that long so I'd like to ask if this type of badge has been implemented before?

From the revisions history it seems that Jeff's changed the status in 2010 for status-completed and then in 2012 the status-declined.

What's the story behind it? Would it be alright to re-apply for this feature or once declined just forget about it?

*I read somewhere that one an old feature request has been declined a long time ago it would be OK to post another request as circumstances around Stack Overflow have changed. Too bad I can't find the link where I read this :(*

Comment: Reading the comment thread on there makes me think it was simply a mistake to tag it [tag:status-completed].

Comment: Indeed, it does seem like a mistake but I think there must have been some misunderstanding as [the linked answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/bounty-hunter-badges/59064#59064) does not include the `Bounty Hunter` badge. They're badges for awarding a bounty to someone etc not getting rewared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jeff Atwood [added new badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59064/187824) related to bounty. And made it [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). But the badges were not what [OP(and other community) wanted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/bounty-hunter-badges#comment159563_59064). After more than 2 years [@TCPMAN.EXE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/153001/tcpman-exe) added a bounty which draw attention of Jeff Atwood once again then he replaced [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) with [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

Comment: yep that makes sense - still I dont understand the why theyve declined it :(

Comment: @mehow - Because they didn't implement it. :) May be they do not want to add more badges for bounty.

Comment: seems pretty reasonable and wanted by the community with 135 upvotes vs -2 downvotes