# Question tagged with both [status-declined] AND [status-completed] - how is this possible?

Tags: discussion, moderator-tags

So I don't know what to think about [this question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179093/get-rid-of-the-question-ban-on-meta-suspend-actively-harmful-users-manually)

It has several tags, but is it marked as both [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) AND [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), i.e. it was both declined and accepted in the same time... ?

I saw a question: [How does a question go from a status-completed to status-declined?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210181/how-does-a-question-go-from-a-status-completed-to-status-declined) I'm pretty sure it wasn't BOTH at once.

Comment: It explains [in the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197335/254250).

Comment: @ff524 OK, but why can't I search for both?

Comment: Don't know what you mean: [this search works fine for me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed+status-declined)

Comment: It could be that I wasn't logged in when I tried the search. Would that make a difference?

Comment: [We only allow a single tag search for anonymous users at this time.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243962/254250)

Comment: It might be nice to have a notice when you try to search like that. Ignore my stupidity.

Comment: @Patrick I have edited out the bug, now it's a valid question unrelated to it.

Answer (score 6):

The [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197335/245360) explains it all, a part of the feature requested has been implemented. The other part hasn't been implemented and won't be. Hence, it has [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) and [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) at the same time.

Now you see the importance of asking one question a time :)

Answer (score 3):

This was [brought up in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4686368#4686368) a while ago, so I'll repeat my replies here.

Essentially, it means that part of the feature request has been declined, while other part accepted and implemented.

Using a [different example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174743/improvements-to-the-mod-only-migrate-tool), the OP asked for two things. One was done (moderators can no longer remigrate a question), and the other declined (moderators can still migrate to every child meta, request to change this declined). Having only one of the tags would be technically wrong.