# "Sidekick" badge

Tags: feature-request, comments, badges, badge-request

Assuming that the primary purpose of badges is to encourage contribution rather than discourage, perhaps we should have a Sidekick badge for those who have high-voted comments on, say, 50 or more accepted answers (or possibly, to widen the criteria, answers with 10 votes or more). Due to the narrow criteria, I would expect this to be a Gold or Silver badge, or perhaps, have different levels as in Nice Sidekick, Good Sidekick and Great Sidekick as corollaries to the Answer and Question badges.

I feel this badge would encourage users to contribute to the good answers.

Obviously, the name can change (to protect the innocent).

Comment: You should add this to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas

Comment: Call it "Peanut Gallery" and I'm with you  :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I do think we need another badge or two that recognizes users contributing stellar comments, and I don't think that it should be limited to great answers. Surely a highly-voted comment on a mediocre or bad answer also deserves consideration?

I'm actually surprised that I can only find [one other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas/274#274) suggested badge that deals with comment quality.

**edit:** [It looks like I've been heard](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/reversal-and-pundit-badges/)

Comment: Yes, I think another badge for high upvotes is also in order. Sidekick for upvotes on good answers/questions, and perhaps a Running Commentary badge for those with just high upvotes on a comment.

Comment: I don't know, if we have a "running commentary" badge, I'm not sure what need we have for a "sidekick" badge. I don't think that commenting on great answers is any more noteworthy than commenting on regular answers.

Comment: That's a good point. If you have one, the other is pretty much covered. I guess that having it for upvoted answers or questions encourages people to contribute to good posts whereas having it for any comment just encourages people to comment. Perhaps the latter is a better goal to have, as you suggest.

Comment: Great. another badge (actually 2 - see Reversal) that I'm not going to get ;)