# Please add a new badge called "Good sport"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, badge-request, sportsmanship-badge

The first time someone votes up another user's answer on a question that they themselves have answered, they should get a bronze "Good sport" badge.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102

Comment: Ah yes, that is the same idea - thanks for pointing it out!  And note that the top ranked answer is the same idea as this suggestion... :)

Answer (score 9):

This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) through the silver [Sportsmanship](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/119/sportsmanship) badge, earned by upvoting 100 competing answers.

Answer (score 6):

I think this idea has merit, but as you've described it, it doesn't do enough to encourage positive behavior on an ongoing basis.  What if the badge was repeating and you got one every 10 (or 25, or 50...) times you upvoted a competing answer?

Comment: Yep, that could work.  Maybe a silver badge after you've upvoted 100 competing answers, or something significant.

Comment: Not a silver badge, I'd say broze after 50, and maybe silver after every 250 after that.
The bronze one is still easy enough, and the silver badge is something which people wouldn't end up with hundreds of, because as far as I know, the power users have a few thousand votes tops.

Comment: as long as people don't go crazy and just always answer and upvote,

Comment: @CJD: Agreed, but I think the downvotes they'd get for unhelpful answers would prevent most people from trying to game the system to get the badge (I *may* have too much faith in my fellow man).

Answer (score 2):

I personally think we have either enough or too many of the "super-easy" bronze badges that we hand out to newbies when they perform basic functions. This doesn't separate itself enough from the other "first upvote" badge to really make it worthwhile to me.

Comment: OK, so award it once a person has upvoted 10 competing answers?

Comment: I would think that would be much more reasonable.

Comment: why not make it 100? That way we can encourage them to CONTINUE doing it, rather than just doing it a few times to get the badge

Comment: devinb: why not make it 1,000?