# New badge for users having accepted answers for all the questions they asked

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, badge-request

If we want accepted answers for the questions (there are some features encouraging this behaviour already) there can be badge for users having accepted answers for all the questions they asked...

edit: I could not find a name yet... ideas appreciated.

Comment: What are the time constraints for this kind of badge?

Answer (score 14):

The danger with this is that it could lead to answers being accepted when they weren't really the definitive answer on the subject and/or people answering their own questions just to accept them.

If the percentage of accepted answers was less than 100% then this might mitigate that as there would be less reason to accept any old answer. To use the numbers from Chaos' answer you could have:

Silver - > 10 questions with 80% accepted
Gold - > 100 questions with 90% accepted.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think this works very well with how badges are currently awarded. Badges are awarded now and you NEVER lose them. This is the case if you get a Nice Answer badge, but then your answer falls down to +9. You will not lose the badge, but it will prevent you from earning a new one if something else happens to come along and earn a badge.

Another problem is "what is ALL the questions they ask?" Are you saying 1 out of 1, 5 out of 5, 10 out of 10? Depending on the size you want this to count, you could also run the risk of people posting garbage questions just so they can do a quick accept (regardless of the quality of the answers).

Answer (score 5):

Idea needs a little work, but the basic motivation is great.  It seems to me that it would need some count threshold, e.g. at least 10 questions asked and 100% have accepted answers (silver) and at least 100 questions asked and 100% have accepted answers (gold).

Let's call the first one Gives Credit and the second one Really Gives Credit. :)

Skip the CW questions for all purposes, too.

Comment: +1 for the name. It's a little shorter then mine.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly excluding community wiki?

I think it would be nice to have the option for CW of saying "this answer doesn't and will never have a correct answer - don't expect me to ever tick it."

Comment: I don't like it when people accept questions like "What the best PC to buy?".

Comment: Even if it is the one the ended up buying.

Answer (score 3):

I asked a question once that was never actually answered.  Then the thing I was asking about stopped happening on my computer, so I couldn't verify an answer in any case.  I gave a few upvotes to answers that seemed helpful, but asking me to accept an answer in order to get a badge would not be helpful.

It also seems to me to be kind of a cheap badge:  ask N questions that each get some sort of answer, randomly accept.

Answer (score 2):

I want that so badly! What would it be called? The I'm an active member who has an obsession with not seeing the "Have you considered starting a bounty?" badge.

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar idea on UserVoice, it involved creating a special class of badges that was revocable. So that if you un-accepted a question, you would lose that badge.

*The UserVoice question had more to do with continuing to look at answers to questions you have asked*

Answer (score 0):

I consider this to be a bad idea.

Attached to people's names is already a percentage of questions accepted.  There are good reasons to to not accept an answer -- an important one is when no one gave a good answer.