# Badge for accepting answers

Tags: feature-request, badges, accepted-answer, badge-request

How about we give a silver badge if someone accepts a certain number of answers (10,25, whatever)?

This might give more incentive to accept answers than the accept-rate.

Possible Name: **`Appreciative`** or maybe **`Learned`** (open for ideas here).

Comment: Duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6930/new-badge-for-users-having-accepted-answers-for-all-the-questions-they-asked (among others)

Comment: @ChrisF, that's not even a duplicate, I checked it out first, that badge request is for a badge for having ALL of your questions have accepted answers, which I think should be the rarest badge of all (after the generalist), since not all questions deserve accepted answers

Comment: @Lance - It was the first that I found & the discussion in the answers is about awarding it for having certain numbers or percentages accepted.

Comment: @ChrisF, ahh, the answers.  I think yours is a good one on that, unfortunately the team won't see the answer come up on their feature-request search (one of our SO dilemmas).  If you post your answer as a feature-request for a badge I'd upvote that as I did your answer.

Comment: I confess my first reaction was "Sure, let's *reward* the question pumps!" Probably that says more about me than anyone else. And while that may not be enough for me to vote against this, it *is* enough for me to not vote for it.

Comment: @Lance - I would hope that the team reads all the answers when evaluating a feature request. There might be something that turns a bad idea into a good idea and equally something that points out the fatal flaw in what otherwise would be a killer feature.

Answer (score 5):

So you want a badge in *addition* to +2 the rep bonus?  If the rep bonus and constant badgering doesn't get them to accept more answers, what makes you think a badge will?

Comment: +1 The interminable fugue on the theme of "You should accept more answers" is whiny and just a little gauche.

Comment: @dmckee - yeah, I dislike accept badgerers about as much as I like wiki-bullying.  Imagine how much worse the whining would be if only accepted answers gained rep!

Comment: I can also see it leading to asking more useless questions to get enough questions to qualify for the badge (some of us, especially on SU, answer a lot more questions than we do ask)

Comment: I hate the badgering also (also as much as I hate wiki-bullying), that's one of the reasons I thought of this.  To give people positive motivation to accept answers instead of negative ones.

Answer (score 4):

Trying to be more objective, here are my 2 cents....

The problem of users not accepting answer can be categorised to some (not all) of these:

1. the OP don't bother
2. the answers (if any) are not satisfactory (from the OP's perspective)
3. the OP doesn't know the importance of accepting an answer
4. the OP went on holiday

How can the proposed badge help?

1. the OP don't bother
   *Might motivate the OP to accept*
2. the answers (if any) are not satisfactory (from the OP's perspective)
   *Might cause the OP to accept answers for the sake of accepting*
3. the OP doesn't know the importance of accepting an answer
   *He might not know of the existence of badge too*
4. the OP went on holiday
   *Ermm.. still on holiday*

What ELSE can the badge do:

- Encourages more questions (despite the quality/genuinity) for the sake of accepting an answer, for the sake of the badge
- Neglecting those who answer lots more than questioning (not a real problem for me though)
- After obtaining the badge, an user then go on a spree without accepting questions unless of course there's a 'gold' one for a higher number of accepted question. So what's after that?

Comment: I'm sure they'll roll out the platinum badges then.

Comment: @Lance, ah.. I wonder what color will that be since silver is used. white?

Answer (score 3):

I've only asked seven questions on Stack Overflow, so I would say no, because I would be ineligible for this badge. :)

Moreover, I don't want to feel pressured to accept answers for the questions where I have not done so thusfar. In my opinion, these questions have not adequately been answered, so they *should* stay unaccepted as a symbol that I am still soliciting good answers for these questions.

Comment: I only have 22 questions on SO, so I probably wouldn't see one right away either.

Comment: I agree, to some extent a 100% accept rate is just as bad as a 0% accept rate. It is normal to have some questions that don't have "good enough" answers yet.

Comment: you wouldn't be pressured to accept answers for *all* your questions, only a certain number of them. i don't think it'd be any more pressure than you already have from the accept rate.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a 2 rep incentive to accept, and also a nice green indicator of you accept ratio, which is more than enough incentive IMO

Besides, this would encourage asking (forced) 10,25 questions only to accept answers and get that badge, with all that implies.

I see only disadvantages.