# No badges for this?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How about a badge for having some quantity of accepted answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67659/how-about-a-badge-for-having-some-quantity-of-accepted-answers)

100 of your answers to other questions accepted  silver
1000 of your answers to other questions accepted gold (can be awarded multiple times)

Seems like those would be some good badges...

Comment: Are you suggesting that these badges go to the person who accepts 100/1000 answers to their questions, or to the person who has that number of their answers accepted?

Comment: @bill clarified inline

Comment: Duplicate of [How about a badge for having some quantity of accepted answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67659/how-about-a-badge-for-having-some-quantity-of-accepted-answers)

Answer (score 4):

Accepted answers are already eligible for other badges (e.g. Enlightened). In other words, it would really just give extra badges to people who already get a lot of them. I don't think that's really a good plan.