# Why not get reputation when your question is marked a favorite by somebody?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, up-votes, bookmarks

I apologize if this has already been asked.  I searched for information but couldn't find any.  I was wondering why reputation isn't given when somebody marks your answer as a favorite.  I have a question that has been marked more times as a favorite then given up votes.  I would think the amount of times the answer was marked as a favorite would at most be equal to the number of up votes.  If a user marks a question as a favorite, I would think the question would automatically get up voted.  Maybe there's a reason for not having it work this way?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Because Favorites more or less act as bookmarks and not always because it was of special quality. I know some of us don't even like the idea of awarding badges based upon how many people mark it as a favorite.

Comment: You took the words right out of my mouth. +1

Comment: Also, due to the fact that you can't favorite answers (yet?), I sometimes favorite a question that I consider stupid because there's an answer that has extra info I find useful or interesting.

Comment: Good point Darth.

Comment: I often use it as a temporary bookmark to questions that I've requested more info from the OP. I don't want to reward me having to check back on the question to see whether or not I can actually answer it yet.

Comment: @mafutrct Or rather, the letters out of your fingers.

Answer (score 14):

Sometimes a question will be marked as favorite because of an answer to that question.

There might be some really horrible questions out there that still manage to attract a great response. It would be folly to give rep in that case.

Comment: I can't really see how a question with a great response would be considered a "horrible question". If a "bad question" attracts some very useful answers, then how can it be considered a bad question?

Comment: Doesn't the fact that a question has a "great response" give the question some value?

Answer (score 10):

As I see it, marking a question as favorite is a rather temporal thing. I mark questions as favorite when I'm curious about the future answers, but when my curiosity has been met, my problem been solved, I usually unmark the question.

I would rather see people upvote questions they favor, as this will be more permanent. This will be [encourage soon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8376/how-to-encourage-voting-on-questions), as it seems.

Answer (score 5):

The word "Favorite" imply that user likes it, but all people, answering this question, are using favorites as bookmarks. So the current name is confusing and BOOKMARK will be a better name. There is a change request 
[Rename "favorite" questions to "subscribed" or "following"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53124/rename-favorite-questions-to-subscribed-or-following)  unfortunately declined due to misunderstanding.

If favorites will be renamed to BOOKMARKs , or if bookmarks will be created additionally to favorites, it will avoid confusion.

Comment: Internet Explorer has used "Favorite" as a synonym for Netscape's "Bookmark" since the early days of the web. I doubt anyone is really confused.

Comment: The „favorites” thing gets really weird in eg. MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

One favorite use-case I have - the most frequent one - is to mark a post that has problems I can't address properly because I've run out of flags.  If the OP gets rep for my 'favorite' I don't really mind, as long as the rep is taken back when I 'un-favorite'.  But from the OP point of view, gaining rep, then having it taken away again a day or two later doesn't sound like great fun.  In any case, we already have voting to show 'favor', or not.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with OP. When someone puts a question in his favorites, it's to find it easily, so it has a strong interest in this question. It may be for its own projects, general culture, etc.

The question is useful to this person.

I see things like this:

- up-vote for the quality of the question
- up-favorite for the usefulness of the question

So I think we should get points when someone marks our question in favorite.

Comment: And in the common case where I downvote and favourite the same question?