# Rep for being favorited?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why not get reputation when your question is marked a favorite by somebody?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8457/why-not-get-reputation-when-your-question-is-marked-a-favorite-by-somebody)

Is it worth giving some form of rep for being favorited? Taking [an example](https://superuser.com/questions/349/keeping-folders-synced-between-several-machines) - this has been favourited 7 times, but only upvoted 5 times - maybe this goes back to [How to encourage voting on questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8376/how-to-encourage-voting-on-questions).

I'd suggest that a question that has been favourited is as much a sign that it was a good question as if it were upvoted, and perhaps needs to be rewarded as such?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8457

Comment: I have to be honest, I wouldn't normaly expect a rep request like question from someone of your rep level on SO and meta.

Comment: I'm not requesting in a vanity thing - there have been a lot of rumblings about people just plain not voting on questions...

Comment: ...and why jump so violently on this, compared to the dupe that again, couldn't be found via search

Comment: @Rowland - It's ok, on meta, downvotes are just like people saying they disagree with your question. Try to not take things personal here. It is a valid request, just not well recieved.

Comment: @Troggy I just found it odd that this attracted a slew of downvotes, yet the dupe hadn't (overall, at least). Such is life. My real gripe is with the weakness of the search on here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are already a couple of **badges** which reward favorite-ed questions. Badged are used to reward activities which are not heralded by the reputation system. **I think that should pretty much cover it.**

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes I favorite bad questions because I want to see what happens.

Comment: Train wrecks are *awesome*!

Comment: I run other drivers off the road just so I can double back and drive slowly past the scene of the crash.

Comment: I favorited this question.

Comment: Sometimes I favorite an iffy question because I want to make sure that my side is represented.

Comment: @Spencer your only favourite on MSO too - I *should* feel honoured...

Answer (score 3):

I do not agree with giving rep for being favorited because being favorited doesn't necessarily mean "This question rocks". Often times people will favorite something just so they can reference it again in the future (not necessarily a good thing).

I don't even agree with the badge giving for acquiring favorite marks, but that is another topic in itself.

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one that doesn't like those badges.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. I sometimes favorite a question based on an answer not the question itself. Sometimes it is even one that I want to come back to and decide if I should vote to close or not. It might even be one that I explicitly down voted and I want to come back to participate in comment discussion.

Favorite != Good.