# Improve the search algorithm to work with tag synonyms

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, tag-synonyms

I just made a random search for some tag that were on the *Source* column of the [Tag Synonym page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) (in this case[`[flex4]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex4)), and noticed two things:

1. The script to auto rename is not working at full warp yet on some older posts.
2. The search algorithm doesn't consider the synonyms.

Comment: Be aware that this is related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15543/have-some-level-of-checking-synonyms-in-search but is not an exact duplicate (the tag synonyms didn't exist back then).

Comment: Re: 1 -- Currently, adding a synonym does not automatically retag questions (it probably should).

Comment: @Jon: There is a column called *Last Auto Rename*, which I assumed did just that.

Comment: New uses of a mapped synonym get changed automatically to the target tag.  That's what the *Last Auto Rename* column is recording.  Questions that existed before synonyms went in aren't being retagged automatically when a synonym mapping is created.  I thought they should too.  I went in and did merge some of them manually, but hopefully it will be automated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so if

- the question count is 0 for a `/questions/tagged/` route
- it's for a single tag

we test to see if that's a synonym, and if so, redirect to the parent.

Comment: Doesn't work as expected for multi-tag searches; for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+mysqldb

Comment: @mikey irrelevant, if there is more than one tag this logic is skipped

Answer (score 4):

There are complicating factors here:

1. Tag synonyms only affect the future – they do not fix the past; we still need to run merges. If mods are being slow in this department, post a question on meta.
2. If, for example, you had a synonym [csharp](/questions/tagged/csharp) => [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23):

   - a. When a user types in `csharp` in the text box and hits enter, should it search for `c#`? What if there are still questions tagged [csharp](/questions/tagged/csharp)? (Now you can not find them.)
   - b. Perhaps the user really wanted to search for `csharp` in the post body?

I'm tempted to decline this as it feels too complicated.

Comment: If they wanted to search for csharp in the post body instead of tags, they just don't enter it as a tag search. We shouldn't mess with non-tag items when dealing with tag synonyms.

Comment: Re: 2 -- (a) Isn't the point of synonyms such that there *shouldn't be any questions in the source tag*? and (b) then they have to use the proper notation to search by free text -- even without synonyms, seaching for "csharp" (no quotes) would autodetect it as a tag. If an autodetected tag gets transformed through the synonyms, the user should find relevant content anyway.

Comment: If you absolutely must keep the old tags around, then update the search to include results from *both* the parent *and* child tags.  You should be able to do this just by rewriting the query, without changing the search algorithm at all.  This solves both issues, doesn't it?

Comment: Excuse me if I'm oversimplifying the scope of the issue. I understand it might require architecture changes to do an "OR" tag search. However, it seems like the solution is when searching for "[synonym]", the search engine should instead search for "[synonym] or [master]". Whether or not that's easily achievable is a different story.